# Why does Internet Explorer 8 print invisible content?

Tags: html, css, printing, internet-explorer-8

please check the HTML code below. The 3rd DIV is partially visible because it is overlayed by the 2nd (which has a white background). All good so far, everything displays correctly in both IE and Firefox.

The problem starts when I print the page. In Firefox it prints as displayed on the page. In Internet Explorer 8 it somehow prints all DIVS completely. It looks as if it applies a opacity filter on the 2nd DIV (or all) which makes the 3rd DIV completely visible...

I create a white overlay with new contents (in javascript) for a Print version of a page. Because of the issue described above it doesn't work correctly because all content below the overlay is also printed...

**Why does IE8 print this invisible content? Is there a solution?**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div style="background-color:#999999;position:relative;border:solid 1px black;width:500px;height:500px;">     
    <div style="position:absolute;width:300px;height:200px;top:5px;left:5px;border:dashed 1px #cccccc;z-index:99;background-color:white;"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute;width:100px;height:200px;top:100px;left:50px;border:dashed 5px #cccccc;z-index:98;background-color:white;"></div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: RichieHindle probably has the problem marked. You cannot rely on colors and similar visual tricks when printing - to ensure good contrast on paper every browser manipulates the page to its own specification (you'll love it when your first Opera user tries to print, especially if you use CSS printing suggestions like page breaks). If you want it to print as you see it on screen, you'll need to go with simplicity - only use the primary intended functionality of CSS, don't rely on the side effects to achieve your layout. Most sites just have a seperate printable page for this purpose.

Comment: True he was spot on. However asking for users to change print-settings is not desirable. I ended up hiding the rest of the content which does the job.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IE has an option:

Tools / Internet Options / Advanced / Printing / Print background colours and images

which is off by default.  This is why it's ignoring your `background-color` styles when printing.

Comment: I don't want users to change print settings, so this is not a solution for me. I ended up hiding the rest of the content as Jose Basilio suggested. Your answer however is correct to my question. This also gave me the best insight in the problem!

Answer (score 13):

The ideal solution is to put all your styles inside CSS classes instead of using inline styles. This gives you greater control and you can use the [Media Type](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) to define what is visible on the screen and what gets printed.

Here's an example of how you can approach this with CSS classes and Media Types.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
@media screen,print{
  .container{
     background-color:#999999;position:relative;
     border:solid 1px black;width:500px;height:500px;
  }
}
@media screen {
  .hideForPrint{
     position:absolute;width:100px;height:200px;top:100px;left:50px;
     border:dashed 5px #cccccc;z-index:98;background-color:white;
  }
}

@media print {
  .hideForPrint,.hideForPrint2{
    display:none;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">     
        <div class="hideForPrint"></div>
        <div class="hideForPrint2"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am using different stylesheets for print and screen. This was just an example. I my example the right answer would've been: Add "display:none;" to the 3rd DIV. +1 for giving an answer that is the same as the solution I already had!