# window.print not working with opera browser

Tags: javascript, browser, opera

I am trying to open a print dialog box in Opera browser using javascript code as

```
<script language=javascript>
window.print(); //This is working in IE, Netscape, Firefox, but not working in Opera
</script>
```

where as if I am using the following code Opera browser understands and able to open print dialog box

```
<input type="button" value="Print this page" onClick="javascript:window.print();" ID="Button1" NAME="Button1">
```

My requirement is to open print dialog box in Opera browser using script block.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: See this link, hope it will help you.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555697/window-print-not-working-in-ie][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555697/window-print-not-working-in-ie

Comment: Please check my answer on this similar issue:
          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582767/print-not-working-on-opera-browser/8220731#8220731

Answer (score 2):

Try putting your code in `load` event:

```
<script language=javascript>
window.onload = function(){
  window.print();
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the whole web page is loaded in Opera before you call window.print();

So using this may help - not, I am waiting for the page to load AND causing a slight delay, which is a little known fix for some versions of Opera.

Hope it helps.

```
window.onload = function () {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        window.print();
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all of your contribution.very much sorry to inform that these are not working with opera(but woks in other browsers)

Comment: What version of Opera are you using - this works in 10.61. Can you post an example of your page, in case these is some other issue, such as you are adding two onload event handlers.