# How do I print a PDF file using javascript in Opera?

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing

I am able to use javascript to print PDF file in Internet Explorer and Firefox, as such:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
{
    document.write('<object id="agreementPDF" type="application/pdf" data="file.pdf" width="100%" height="500"></object>');
}
else
{
    document.write('<iframe id="agreementFrame" src="file.pdf" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>');
}
//-->
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function printAgreement()
{
    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
    {
        document.getElementById('agreementPDF').print();
    }
    else
    {
        var agreement = document.getElementById('agreementFrame');
        agreement.focus();
        agreement.contentWindow.print();
    }   
}
//-->
</script>

<input type="button" name="print" onclick="printAgreement();" value="Print" />
```

However, in Opera, the print function does not work.

How do I make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Opera needs a little more hand holding when it comes to the print dialog. Here are some very similar questions previously asked/answered on stack**overflow**:

[window.print not working with opera browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482428/window-print-not-working-with-opera-browser)

[print() not working on opera browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582767/print-not-working-on-opera-browser)

[Print iframe content in Opera and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648594/print-iframe-content-in-opera-and-chrome)

Seems like you either need to use a different *.print() function or trigger the event after the page has finished loading.

Hope these links help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried printing on the window's onload event?

```
window.onload = function(){
  window.print();
};
```