# js window.open then print()

Tags: javascript, html, printing, window

print() doesn't work in IE after opening a new window.  It works in Chrome.
Here's a [tester](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_win_focus):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function openWin()
  {
    myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
    myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
    myWindow.focus();
    myWindow.print(); //DOES NOT WORK
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Open window" onclick="openWin()" />

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

checkout: 
[window.print() not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555697/window-print-not-working-in-ie)

Working sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Xc9/1/

Comment: Can you please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448910/window-print-works-on-urls-except-one

Answer (score 22):

Turgut gave the right solution. Just for clarity, you need to add close after writing.

```
function openWin()
  {
    myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
    myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");


    myWindow.document.close(); //missing code


    myWindow.focus();
    myWindow.print(); 
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function printDiv(divName) {
         var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
         var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
         document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
         window.print();
         document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
    }

</script>


<div id="printableArea">CONTENT TO PRINT</div>



<input type="button" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" value="Print Report" />
```

Answer (score 5):

As most of browsers has been updated, So print and close do not any more as It worked before. So you should add **onafterprint** event listener in order to close print window.

```
    var printWindow = window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/');
    printWindow.print();

    //Close window once print is finished
    printWindow.onafterprint = function(){
       printWindow.close()
    };
```

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me was adding `myWindow.document.close()` after `myWindow.document.write()`.  Here's my solution with a timeout to wait for the new window to finish loading (if you have a lot to load):

```
var win = window.open('', 'PrintWindow');
win.document.write('Stuff to print...');

setTimeout(function () {
    win.document.close();
    win.focus();
    win.print();
    win.close(); 
}, 1000);
```

Comment: It´s working indeed, but cannot find why win.document.close() it's need it.

Answer (score 4):

```
function printCrossword(printContainer) {
    var DocumentContainer = getElement(printContainer);
    var WindowObject = window.open('', "PrintWindow", "width=5,height=5,top=200,left=200,toolbars=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,resizable=no");
    WindowObject.document.writeln(DocumentContainer.innerHTML);
    WindowObject.document.close();
    WindowObject.focus();
    WindowObject.print();
    WindowObject.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openWin()
{
myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
myWindow.focus();
print(myWindow);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Open window" onclick="openWin()" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The only solution that worked for me in IE-11. Thanks !!

Comment: On my chrome, the window stays open even after closing the printing window