# javascript: open window and print

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

I've looked at this question: [js window.open then print()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852190/js-window-open-then-print) and it works just fine. My challenge is that I have a lot of styling that I would like to retain in the opened print window. I've tried changing

```
var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=1000,height=700');
```

to

```
var printWindow = window.open('print.aspx', '', 'width=1000,height=700');
```

and then using jQuery like this:

```
$("#print", printWindow.document).html($("#tabContainer").html());
```

but the window I get opened does not contain anything from the actual print.aspx file.

Can anyone shed some light on what's going wrong?

Edit:
This is weird (at least to me)... My print.aspx has this:

```
<body >
    <div id="print">print content here...</div>
</body>
```

and from my calling page this works (returns 1):

```
alert(printWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body').length);
```

but changing 'body' to 'div' makes it "fail" returning 0

Comment: The 2nd one looks fine to me.  What happens when you manually browse to `print.aspx`?

Comment: Unfortunately the servers are down. Will update when they get back up :-/

Comment: Okay I DO get the actual Print.aspx opened but I can't access the div tag with id="print" in the Print.aspx page from my calling page...

Comment: If the div tag is added to your original page dynamically, then it will not show in the newly opened window.

Comment: The div tag is not added dynamically. It's part of the Print.aspx file.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the full url when possible, else it tries to use the relative url.

`var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=1000,height=700');` would open a blank url

`var printWindow = window.open('print.aspx', '', 'width=1000,height=700');` opens page *print.aspx* relative to current url. So if current url is *www.google.com*, it opens *www.google.com/print.aspx*, which would be 404 page not found.

Be careful of some sites which will redirect you, which can confuse you. For example if you run this on current stackoverflow page it would open this page itself because *`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18633800/xxxxxx/print.aspx`* would redirect to *`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18633800/xxxxxx`*

Also the jquery wont work because you cannot copy content from one window to another through javascript. Both are separate and cannot communicate.

Comment: Wouldn't print.aspx be opened relatively to my current aspx page rather than the server?

Comment: See my second comment to OP

Comment: Yes it would open relative to the url. So if current url is xxxxx.aspx your new url would be xxxxx.aspx/print.aspx

Comment: tried alert(printWindow.document.getElementById('print')); right after window.open - returns null even though my print.aspx contains <div id="print">print content here...</div> in the body

Comment: Are you running this from original window ?

Comment: everything is running on the same server. From a.aspx I open b.aspx located in the same directory.