# submit data of form to a popup and print that popup window

Tags: javascript, html

i am using this code to get submitted data from a form

```
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="auto-style8" style="width: 70%" />
<button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return submit();">Submit</button> 
<div id="info"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submit()
    {
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = " My Name is "+name+" ";
    return false;
    }
</script>
```

the result is displayed in the same window as that of form.
i want to display the output in a popup window and be able to link a print button in the main window that once clicked will print the contents of that popup

```
edit: just to clarify more.

form submitted > open a new window > displays the entered results
```

thanks

Comment: So open a new window (window.open) and write to it (document write).

Comment: can you modify this code, thanks

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal

Comment: Try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852190/js-window-open-then-print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can modify your code this way :

```
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="auto-style8" style="width: 70%" />
<button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return submit();">Submit</button> 
<div id="info"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submit()
    {
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = " My Name is "+name+" ";
        var r = window.confirm(" My Name is "+name+" .Click Ok To Print");
        if (r == true) {
            x = window.print();
        }
    return false;
    }
</script>
```

Hope this serves your purpose.

Comment: try this instead .........
var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200, height=100");
    myWindow.document.write("<p>My Name is "+name+" </p>");

Comment: I tried the solution from the previous comment, but for me on google-chrome `window.open` returns `undefined`, which makes this solution inapplicable...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like

```
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="auto-style8" style="width: 70%" />
<button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return submit();">Submit</button> 
<div id="info"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submit()
    {
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        var output = " My Name is "+name+" ";
        var myWindow = window.open("data:text/html," + encodeURIComponent(output),
                   "_blank", "width=200,height=100");

        x = window.print();

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11967627/979978) as inspiration :)