# How to print a PDF file using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, printing

I'm trying to have a link which open up a print preview for a PDF (the PDF is placed near the actual .html page)

I've tried:

```
<script>
function printpdf()
{
    var w = window.open('example.pdf');

    w.onload = function()
    {
        w.print();
    };
}
</script>
```

but it doesn't fire the browser print page. However, the PDF opens up

I also tried the JQuery approach:

```
<script>
function printpdf()
{
    var w = window.open('example.pdf');

    $(w).ready(function(){
        w.print();
    });
}
</script>
```

no luck. The PDF opens but the print preview is not triggered.

What I am missing here?

Comment: Seems this is already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239513/print-pdf-directly-from-javascript

Comment: @DavidR no, it's not the same question: the other one asks for printing without the user seeing the PDF or opening a PDF viewer. They ask for a silent print which I don't need

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17831586/519413

Comment: I don't think `window.print()` is the correct approach here, you better of use a library like https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js and use its api to call the print command.

Comment: download and possibly modify [pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) - I know I've managed to use that to trigger a print when the pdf is fully rendered

Comment: @JaromandaX yes that is correct, I've read the source code and it looks like pdf.js also uses `window.print()` internally so his job is now even more simple, just catch the event once the pdf is rendered and call `window.print()`