# everytime i try to print pdf using this method it will always produce blank pdf

Tags: javascript, html

so i want to print pdf using button and javascript but it will always produce blank pdf/empty pdf. i want something like https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Bm7o.jpg, but i got this instead https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYVuq.jpg

i try using window.open and then window.print but it still produce blank pdf, i also tried to put url inside window.open instead of declaring it first but that didn't work

HTML

```
<button type="button" onclick="printme()">click me...</button>
```

JavaScript

```
function printme(){
 var URL = "https://www.detik.com/";
 var W = window.open(URL);
 W.window.print();
}
```

Comment: maybe this link helps
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852190/js-window-open-then-print

Comment: unfortunately, that link only provide solution if i want to print a text, i want to print a whole website page

Answer (score 2):

you need to do window.print() instead of w.window.print()

```
function printme(){
 var URL = "https://www.detik.com/";
 var W = window.open(URL);
 window.print();
}
```

Comment: you want to print the whole website which is opened through window.open() as a pdf  ?

Comment: not exactly the whole website, just want to print the html on the page i want to print, you can see the example on the link i attached.

Comment: may be this is your solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240472/printing-a-web-page-using-just-url-and-without-opening-new-window

Comment: funny enough that's where i got my original code hehe, didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The source of the following code is [Print an external page without opening it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Printing#Print_an_external_page_without_opening_it)

which was mentioned in one of the answers here [Printing a web page using just url and without opening new window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240472/printing-a-web-page-using-just-url-and-without-opening-new-window)

I only modified the link to include your website address:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>MDN Example</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function closePrint() {
      document.body.removeChild(this.__container__);
    }

    function setPrint() {
      this.contentWindow.__container__ = this;
      this.contentWindow.onbeforeunload = closePrint;
      this.contentWindow.onafterprint = closePrint;
      this.contentWindow.focus(); // Required for IE
      this.contentWindow.print();
    }

    function printPage(sURL) {
      var oHiddFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
      oHiddFrame.onload = setPrint;
      oHiddFrame.style.position = "fixed";
      oHiddFrame.style.right = "0";
      oHiddFrame.style.bottom = "0";
      oHiddFrame.style.width = "0";
      oHiddFrame.style.height = "0";
      oHiddFrame.style.border = "0";
      oHiddFrame.src = sURL;
      document.body.appendChild(oHiddFrame);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>


  <p><span onclick="printPage('https://www.detik.com');" style="cursor:pointer;text-decoration:underline;color:#0000ff;">Print external page!</span></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i tried to run your demon, but i got an error message
Error: {
  "message": "SecurityError: Permission denied to access property \"__container__\" on cross-origin object",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 22,
  "colno": 0
}