# How to print a pdf?

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have  a pdf url, embedded in  a rectangular area of an iframe. I am trying to print it on click of a button . My code looks like this :

**JavaScript to print :**

```
function printPDF(pdfUrl)
{
var w = window.open(pdfUrl);
w.print();
w.close();
}
```

**HTML-Code :**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit"  value="Print"
name="Submit" id="printbtn"
onclick="printPDF('http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf')" /></td>
</tr>
```

Now in MF it is coming like this :

[image]

The problem , its not working properly in  chrome and IE. I have chrome 20 and IE 8. In chrome the print window gets loaded in a new tab(which is ok) but pdf does not get loaded in preview. In IE the pdf just gets opened in a new tab and print prompt does not come up.

Before any one asks me, pdf might have inherent print functionality. but the pdfs that i am processing need to have a print button. People, kindly help me out here. Is there a solution, which is applicable in all the 3 browsers .

Comment: Why not just put `window.print()` on `onload` event of body of your `iframe` page.

Comment: I did not understand what you are telling me to do. onloading a body is a bad move also i think

Comment: Related thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687675/can-a-pdf-files-print-dialog-be-opened-with-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folks, just got a solution , which works fine for me .

```
function printPage(htmlPage)
{
    var w = window.open("about:blank");
    w.document.write(htmlPage);
    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') window.print();
    else w.print();
}
```

So, if it is MSIE, then we can just use : window.print();

Comment: I got this one from : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555697/window-print-not-working-in-ie   by Mr Kyle

Comment: What's the motivation behind using `window.print` for IE and `w.print` for everything else? Surely that just has the effect that if you're in internet explorer, you end up printing the page from which you called `printPage` instead of the URL that you passed to it?