# Can't print from a print popup window in IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I have `window.print()` in a popup window to print. Its working in Chrome but not in IE10. In IE10 its printing the background window. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: This should help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555697/window-print-not-working-in-ie

Comment: genuine question: why are you testing against IE10 instead of IE11?

Comment: We didn't make our application to be compatible with IE11 yet

Comment: genuine question: why wouldn't you be testing against the majority of heavily used browsers/user-agents?

Comment: Right Now 95% of our Product users are on IE10 or lower versions and 4% uses Chrome and only 1% uses other browsers so we dont really test our application with all browers