# window.print() hangs in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to open a `new` window and `print` the contents.

```
var parentHeader= $("head").html();
var parentDivContent = $("#printer_data_1").html();
var newW= window.open("", "", "scrollbars=1,width=200,height=200");
    newW.document.write('<html><head><title>Title</title>'+parentHeader+'</head>');
    newW.document.write('<body><div>');
    newW.document.write(parentDivContent );
    newW.document.write('</div></body></html>');
    newW.document.close();
    newW.print();
    newW.close();
```

When i try to run the above `code`, it hangs in `IE8`, when i comment the below line... it works.

```
newW.document.write('<html><head><title>Title</title>'+parentHeader+'</head>');
```

I want the entire content, styles to be loaded in the head section of new window.

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the third answer on this URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555697/window-print-not-working-in-ie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> want the entire content, styles to be loaded in the head section of
>   new window

Try compiling `html` for `newW` into single string , including `head` `html` `parentHeader` ; setting `name` reference for `newW` at second parameter of call to `window.open()` ; calling `document.write` with single single `html` string as parameter

```
var parentHeader= $("head").html();
var parentDivContent = $("#printer_data_1").html();
var newW= window.open("", "newW", "scrollbars=1,width=200,height=200");
var html = "<html>" 
           + parentHeader // `parentHeader` `head` `html`
           + "<body><div>" 
           + parentDivContent 
           + "</div></body></html>"
newW.document.write(html);
newW.document.close();
newW.print();
newW.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `innerHTML` instead of `document.write`. That could be your issue.

```js
var someVar = 50,
  el = document.getElementById('btn');

function onOpen() {
  var prnt = open();
  prnt.document.title = 'Page Title';
  prnt.document.body.innerHTML = [
    '<h1>',
    'heading of the page',
    someVar,
    '</h1>',
    '<p>A paragraph with text.</p>'
  ].join('');
  prnt.print();
  prnt.close();
}

el.attachEvent('onclick', onOpen);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Print for Legacy IE</title>
</head>

<body>

  <a id="btn" href="#">Link</a>

</body>

</html>
```