# window.print() not working in ie and already tried proper fixes

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, printing

I would like to print a whole page when a button is clicked. I am using window.print() but its not working for ie. I googled for a solution but nothing hellped. Maybe someone know what I am doing wrong.

MyCode:

```
$('#PrintTool').click(function () {
var printVal = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
var newWin = window.open();
newWin.document.write(printVal);
newWin.document.close();
newWin.focus();
newWin.print();
newWin.close();
});
```

I hope you can help me

Answer (score 1):

checkout: [window.print() not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555697/window-print-not-working-in-ie)

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Xc9/1/

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function openWin()
  {
    var myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
    myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");

    myWindow.document.close();
    myWindow.focus();
    myWindow.print();
    myWindow.close();

  }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Open window" onclick="openWin()" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it doesn't work...just opens a new window what it also did previously. When i use a different computer or virtual maschine, it works fine. But on several development maschines it doesnt work. In chrome or firefox all works fine.

Comment: just try this in the following order: myWindow.document.close(); myWindow.focus(); myWindow.window.print(); 
instead of your last three steps.