# print Selected data from web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to print the data of selected `div` instead of whole page,
I am using `window.print()` but its printing the whole web page.

Comment: removing JSP and Java tag. It has nothing to do with them. May be add JavaScript tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print the contents of a DIV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do as shown in following example:

```
   <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css" media="print">
    @media print
    {
    #non-printable { display: none; }
    #printable {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="printable" >
    Your content to print
    </div>
    <div id='non-printable'>
    this is not printable section
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="non-printable" class=normaltext onclick="JavaScript:window.print();" value="print" />
    </body>
    </html>
```

for more detail or download visit the site:

http://blog.developeronhire.com/print-selected-div-in-web-page/

Answer (score 1):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

How about writing a style sheet for print and set it up to show the relevant elements on the page.

Answer (score 1):

If you know which segments you want to print before hand, you can use media based CSS to hide unwanted segments of the page in print. Have a look at

http://www.killersites.com/articles/newsletterArchive/Newsletter_Nov3_2003.htm