# print content of jquery dialog with scrollbar

Tags: jquery, html, printing

So I instantiate a new jquery ui dialog window with specified height where the content causes the scrollbar to appear. I have a print button within the dialog window that's meant to print all the content in the dialog window.

It currently only prints the rows that are visible.

Any ideas as to how i can print the whole lot?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use css table for print, like that:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />`

And set `height` there.

---

**Update**:

Try to use [jQuery.printElement](http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/) jquery-plugin for your object:

```
$('SelectorToPrint').printElement();
```

Comment: My Jquery dialog window height is very large here...Please suggest any other way through that i can print all contents of dialog.

Comment: @Pankaj Agarwal Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Jason on 
[Print the contents of a DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div) and the plugin he authored worked great for me.

The following is the css I added in Print.css file that I referenced to:

```
@media print {
.Printable {
    display: block;
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
}

.Printable .Content {
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 700px; /* my specific requirement */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px;
}}

 $("#Container .Printable").printThis({
        debug: false,
        importCSS: true,
        printContainer: false,
        loadCSS: "../Print.css",``
        pageTitle: "TITLE",
        removeInline: false
    });

<link href="../Print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../Scripts/printThis.js"></script>
```