# print the content of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

I need to print whole content of a div. Notice scroll in the div.
But when I use `Window.print()` to print its content, it prints only the visible part on the screen. I want to print all 154 records in the grid, but it prints only 21 records.

[image]

Note: **I don't want to open a new window.**

**EDIT:**

```
javascript function()
{
1. Hide divs that you don't want to print
2. window.print()
3. show the divs you hide in step 1
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you if you don't help-me with some codes.

Comment: @vaibhav, use this jquery plugin `http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/`

Comment: did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div

Comment: See edit for the logic I am using.

Answer (score 1):

The strongest solution I think is to create an iframe, copy the contents to be printed to that frame, then print it. There are JQuery plugins for this. Duplicate: [Print the contents of a DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div)

Another possibility is to have a print CSS that hides the stuff that you don't want to print (menus etc.), and also removes the min-height on your table, causing the scrollbar to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Use  style sheet with a media type of print -

```
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css"
```

And change the DIV style -

```
height:auto;
overflow:auto
```

When printing (use `window.print()`) the DIV will increase in height, and hide all the other DIVs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, But first include this [library](http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/)

```
$('YourDiv').printElement();
```

Or

Read this article on [Div Printing](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1591-Ask-Ben-Print-Part-Of-A-Web-Page-With-jQuery.htm)

Comment: printElement()..Do I need to use some lib for this?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jasonday/jquery.printThis

I wrote the above plugin based on several others, that allows for printing of an element on a page (no popup) and maintaining page styles or loading new css styles specifically for the print element.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482477/how-do-i-print-the-entire-bootstrap-modal-where-content-in-modal-body-is-scrolle/29523921#29523921

Answer (score 0):

I used printThis and it works great with div's that have a fixed height and scrollbar.   ***removeInline: true*** property prints the entire document even though you can see only a part of it in the div.

```
function printpage(divId, title) {
                    var divID = "#" + divId;
                    var divTitle = title;
                    $(divID).printThis({
                        debug: false,
                        importCSS: true,
                        importStyle: true,
                        printContainer: true,
                        pageTitle: divTitle,
                        removeInline: true,
                        printDelay: 333,
                        header: null,
                        formValues: true
                    });

                }
```