# How do I print the entire bootstrap modal where content in modal body is scrolled out of view

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, printing, bootstrap-modal

The problem is that the user has to scroll down to view all of the content within the modal body. However, when I print the modal the only part that is printed is the part that is viewable. I want the entire modal's content to be printed. I have tried every piece of code on the following page and none of them print the entire modal.

[Twitter Bootstrap: Print content of modal window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181760/twitter-bootstrap-print-content-of-modal-window)

Comment: Have you tried increasing the modal's height to accommodate its entire content before printing? You might alternatively try changing its `overflow-y` setting to `overflow-y:visible`.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Yes I tried it after you suggested it, but I couldn't get it to print the content that was still out of view only without the scrollbar now. You got me on the right track though. I ended up using the plugin printThis by Jason Ray.

Comment: Good detective work. Could you post an answer to your own question please, and include a link to the plugin?

Comment: The height of the modal dialog for print media should be increased to allow for all the content to print. Take a look at this approach: This is an approach using CSS classes. http://www.ozkary.com/2015/06/angularjs-print-bootstrap-modal-content.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Download printThis.js from the following link and include it in your html: https://github.com/jasonday/printThis/blob/0a7f799693af8a8303bf0b8df0efc80c2694af81/printThis.js

Wrap the content you want to print with the following div. Everything outside of this div will not be printed.

```
<div id="modalDiv">
    ..content to print..
</div>
```

Call the following jquery to print all the content including the content that is not viewable. You may include your css files in an array if you have multiple css files.

```
$("#modalDiv").printThis({ 
    debug: false,              
    importCSS: true,             
    importStyle: true,         
    printContainer: true,       
    loadCSS: "../css/style.css", 
    pageTitle: "My Modal",             
    removeInline: false,        
    printDelay: 333,            
    header: null,             
    formValues: true          
});
```

Comment: I try this, but it does not add new page

Comment: I used this, it opens the print window but not show any thig? any idea about this?

Answer (score 24):

Was facing the same issue with angularjs UI bootstrap library. Tried the link provided above but no luck. The only CSS that works for me when the modal is **LONGER** than the view port is:

```
@media print {
    .modal {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: visible!important;
    }
}
```

Note: `position:absolute` and `overflow:visible` are **MUST** have. 
Hope this could also solve your problem when printing angularUI-Bootstrap-Modal.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me.  I tried many jQuery and straight up JavaScript and lots of CSS.  Thanks.

Comment: Seriously beautiful solution

Comment: This is a great solution, but in IE&EDGE page background is still visible

Comment: note: this will **not** work if you have `modal-dialog-scrollable` on your `modal-dialog` like the second one mentioned [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/#scrolling-long-content)

Answer (score 10):

I think you can easily do that with CSS using `@media print`:

If there is opened bootstrap modal window, will be printed content of modal (it can be more than one page), in other case content of window.

```
@media print {
    /* on modal open bootstrap adds class "modal-open" to body, so you can handle that case and hide body */
    body.modal-open {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    body.modal-open .modal .modal-header,
    body.modal-open .modal .modal-body {
        visibility: visible; /* make visible modal body and header */
    }
}
```

Also you can add button on footer of modal for printing:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="js:window.print()">print modal content</button>
</div>
```

Comment: worked like a charm, most methods I saw were either too much for my use case or too long to implement!

Comment: it works, but it is displayed as XS settings instead of lg settings (it is displayed as one column per row instead of two columns per row as I see in the screen). Is there any way to print exactly what I am seeing?

Comment: @FranciscoG It means some style (e.g. for lg settings) writed under `@media screen` instead of `@media all` (which is default @media type).

Answer (score 1):

http://plnkr.co/edit/fspygnqWhsosqDTds0Og?p=preview

```
/**Modal Styles for Print**/

        @media print {
          body * {
            visibility: hidden;
          }
          #print-content * {
            visibility: visible;
            overflow: visible;
          }
          #mainPage * {
            display: none;
          }
          .modal {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            min-height: 550px;
            visibility: visible;
            /**Remove scrollbar for printing.**/
            overflow: visible !important;
            position: relative;
          }
          .modal-dialog {
            visibility: visible !important;
            /**Remove scrollbar for printing.**/
            overflow: visible !important;
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Abu Sulaiman: Using this still prints out only the part showing in the modal. To also show the hidden part especially when your content is overflow, change the `removeInline: true`just as done below. Works fine for me.

Download printThis.js from the following link and include it in your html: https://github.com/jasonday/printThis/blob/0a7f799693af8a8303bf0b8df0efc80c2694af81/printThis.js

Wrap the content you want to print with the following div. Everything outside of this div will not be printed.

..content to print..

Call the following jquery to print all the content including the content that is not viewable. You may include your css files in an array if you have multiple css files.

```
$("#modalDiv").printThis({ 
    debug: false,              
    importCSS: true,             
    importStyle: true,         
    printContainer: true,       
    loadCSS: "../css/style.css", 
    pageTitle: "My Modal",             
    removeInline: true,        
    printDelay: 333,            
    header: null,             
    formValues: true          
});
```