# How do you link a button to a printThis function

Tags: javascript, jquery, printthis

I am trying to work out how to print an image from Magnific Lightbox & came across this excellent answer below.

[How do I print the entire bootstrap modal where content in modal body is scrolled out of view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482477/how-do-i-print-the-entire-bootstrap-modal-where-content-in-modal-body-is-scrolle/39464659?noredirect=1#comment66249739_39464659)

It seems @Abu-Sulaiman has the most popular answer but this newbie can't work out how to link to a button. From my most basic knowledge, the id of the button is used at the start of the function (in this case "#modalDiv") however it appears that the div I'd of their area to be printed is used in that location.

Ive also come across another post thanks to a helpful member but this seems more simpler.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Todd

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using jQuery (because printThis requires jQuery):

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
    $('#myDiv').printThis();
});
```