# Print text from few div

Tags: jquery

I see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2255438/1511551), but how to proceed to print text from second, third div?
This is what I want to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function PrintElem(elem)
{
    Popup($(elem).text());
}
function Popup(data) 
{
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'Coupon', 'height=300,width=710');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Coupon</title>');
    /*optional stylesheet*/ mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="cupon.css" type="text/css" />');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body ><div class="coupon_logo"><img src="discount.jpg"></div><div class="coupon_conditions">');
             mywindow.document.write(data); // text from first div
    mywindow.document.write('</div>');
    mywindow.document.write('<div class="coupon_clinic_info">');
            //text from second div
    mywindow.document.write('</div>');
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "**print** text from div"? What are you trying to achieve? Please explain your problem properly so that we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine it would be fine simply applying a class to all the divs you wish to print

```
<div id="mydiv" class="toprint">
    This will be printed. 
</div>

<div>
    This will not be printed.
</div>

<div id="anotherdiv" class="toprint">
    This will be printed.
</div>
```

Then using the answer to the question you quoted, changing this line:

```
<input type="button" value="Print Div" onclick="PrintElem('.toprint')" />
```

Comment: And yes for fun I tested it and it does work as expected.

Comment: Good to hear! Thanks for giving it a test :)

Comment: Now that the question was edited, I believe this is the right answer.

Comment: so it prints the entire text is inextricably