# javascript function fires with alert but not without

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple javascript function to print the current page:

```
<script>
    function printpage() {
        window.print();
        alert("PRINTING...");
    }
</script>
```

and the call:

```
<a href="#" onclick="printpage()" data-role="button" data-theme="j">Print</a>
```

If I remove the alert the print popup box doesn't show until I refresh the page.  With the alert there is a short pause and then it shows, I would prefer not to have any alert.  I tried doing a console.log instead so an event would happen invisibly to the user and still fire the function but it didn't work.

The solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div) works great for single divs and fires immediately but I need to print the entire page and would prefer to stick with a simple `window.print()`.

EDIT: More details, when I click refresh, the print dialog pops up and the page does not refresh until you actually close the dialog, similar to the way the dialog doesn't show until I close the alert.

Comment: Are you using something like jQuery UI?

Comment: Works [fine to me](http://jsfiddle.net/QxT6m/).

Comment: What browser (version) are you using?

Comment: @Bergi chrome 27.0.1453.116 m

Comment: onclick="printpage();return false;"

Comment: just some random thoughts: what happens if you omit the `window` and just write `print()`? Or what happens if you write `this.print()`?

Comment: @basilikum `print()` works but with the same behavior and `this.print()` does not work at all.

Comment: Ok, I think I remember having a similar problem and it had something to do with that the `document` wasn't closed or was still in use somehow or something like this. That's all I can recall right now but maybe it's something else entirely. Do you use `document.write` to create parts of your page? If so, try to write `document.close()` after everything is written.

Comment: @basilikum I'm not using `document.write` but thanks everyone for taking a stab at it. I'll update if I solve this.

Comment: Don't you have any errors in your `WebKit Inspector/FireBug` ? I would really like to see the page itself, I'm pretty sure it's a forgotten comma or a similar mistake (that we all do 50 times per day).

Answer (score 0):

Your source work without the alert. See it at : http://jsfiddle.net/WwXwr/1/. (tested on Chrome 27.0.1453.116 and ie 10  / Windows 8)

It can also be replaced by :

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.print()" data-role="button" data-theme="j">Print 2</a>
```

Comment: The error must be in a other place in your page. This just confirm that the code works. Try to add details or try to reproduce the problem on a jsfiddle because the code should be correct.