# Print a page by given URL

Tags: javascript, php, css, printing

I have a website which consists of 5 pages. I have created a special page called print_page.php which contains the contents of all 5 pages.

How can I add a link at the top of the 5 individual pages which when pressed will print the contents of the print_page.php?

Thanks for any help

Comment: You could link to 'print_page.php' and then with JavaScript print the page and go back to previous page but that is an ugly solution.

Comment: Or you could include your 'print_page.php' in your current page and use CSS to hide it and show it on print.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need that separate page?

First opportunity -- include that print_page.php to a div, that is visible only on print:

```
<div class="print_only"><?php include('print_page.php'); ?></div>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen {
.print_only { display: none; }
}

@media print {
.print_only { display: block; }
}
```

Then print it with window.print();

Second opportunity is to re-design your site to have relevant printable content on all pages designed with @media appropriately.

Answer (score -1):

You can define every page as a block in print_page.php.
So, when you are on page1, print page url will contain something like

```
 <a href="print_page.php?id=firstpage".
```

Then you show content depending on id variable.

Comment: Not sure if your following or I don't understand. I don't want the user to see print_page.php. I just want the contents of this page to print when they press the print button on any of the 5 pages?

Comment: I've made edit but it's not visible.
Make hidden div (display: none) and print only the content that div contains.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div

Answer (score -1):

I think you would need to use javascript to accomplish this.

```
<a href="print_page.php" onClick ="window.print();return false">
```