# How to print a gridview and textboxes in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

I want to print the gridview and the textboxes beside it. but the textboxes should be at the top and the gridview should be below the textboxes..

I have this code and it only prints the gridview:

```
function printDiv(DivID1)
{
    var headstr = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>";
    var footstr = "</body>";
    var newstr = document.getElementById("dt").innerHTML;
    var oldhtml = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = headstr + newstr + footstr;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = oldhtml;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why you passed _DivID1_ parameter when you are not using it ? Also, _"<html><head><title></title></head><body>"_ and _</body>_ should not be included in _document.body.innerHTML_ because it only contains content inside _<body>...</body>_.

Comment: I placed a divID1 in the gridview.<div id="dt"> <div id=DivID1></div></div>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvDoc1" CssClass="CSSTableGenerator" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
         DataKeyNames="TrackingID"

Answer (score 0):

if you can use jQuery try [printThis()](https://github.com/jasonday/printThis) plugin, you can put all the controls or the html you need whitin a div and use that div in the selector for printing.

there´s another plugin named [printElement()](http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/)

or try this answer described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div),

```
<script language="javascript">
function printdiv(printpage)
{
var headstr = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>";
var footstr = "</body>";
var newstr = document.all.item(printpage).innerHTML;
var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = headstr+newstr+footstr;
window.print();
document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;
return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: what will i place in the (printpage)

Comment: try to put a container there like a div (that should contain the gridview and the textboxes), it seems like is pretty much the same solution you already have done but just bet that the document.all.iteam maybe can do the trick...

Comment: can you paste your html not all but the wrapper that contains the items you want to print?