# print function is calling before partial view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What I am trying to do is to open partial view in new window and call print function, but problem is that partial view renders after print function so I always get a blank page. I tried with `$timeout` function but I get the same result. For now, I have this but this is a hacky solution and I don't like it:

```
$scope.print = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        print()
    }, 1000);
}
```

This is html of page that i try to open:

```
<div id="printWrapper" style="background-color:white;" ng-controller="accountContentController" ng-init="print()">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <!-- HEADER -->
        <tr>
            <td>

                <img id="imgLogo" src="@Model.TicketPayOut.Logo" />


            </td>
        </tr>
        <!--HEADER-->
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label id="lblTerminalId" class="left-position padding-top-3 padding-left-3 text-style">@Translator.Translate("TERMINAL")</label>
                <span class="left-position padding-top-3 text-style">:</span>
                <label id="lblTerminalIdValue" class="left-position padding-top-3 padding-left-3 text-style"></label>

                <div style="clear:both"></div>

                <label id="lblTerminalName" class="left-position padding-left-3 text-style">@Translator.Translate("BET_OFFICE")</label>
                <span class="left-post text-style">:</span>
                <label id="lblTerminalNameValue" class="left-position padding-left-3 text-style"></label>

                <label id="lblTerminalCityAddress" class="left-position padding-left-3 text-style" style="clear:both;"></label>

                <label id="lblCompanyInfo" class="center-position text-style" style="clear:both;"></label>
                <label id="lblCompanyAddress" class="center-position text-style" style="clear:both;"></label>
                <label id="lblCompanyId" class="center-position text-style" style="clear:both;"></label>

            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="border-top border-bottom">
                <div style="padding:10px 0;">
                    <label id="lblStornoMessage" class="center-position text-style">@Translator.Translate("PAYOUT_CONFIRMATION")</label>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="border-bottom">

                <div style="height:25px;padding:10px 3px 0 3px;">
                    <label id="lblPayoutTicket" class="left-position text-style">@Translator.Translate("PAYOUT_TICKET")</label>
                    <label id="lblPinValue" class="right-position text-style">{{payoutTime | date: dateFormat }}</label>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>
                <div style="padding:5px 3px;">

                    <label id="lblPinTicket" class="left-position text-style">@Translator.Translate("PIN")</label>
                    <label id="lblPinReturnValue" class="right-position text-style">{{ticketPin}}</label>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="padding:5px 3px;">
                    <label id="lblPayinReturn" class="left-position text-style">@Translator.Translate("PAYOUT_AMOUNT")</label>
                    <label id="lblPayinReturnValue" class="right-position text-style">{{payoutAmount}}</label>
                </div>

            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td class="border-bottom">
                <div style="padding:25px 3px 5px 3px;">
                    <label id="lblCreatedBy" class="left-post text-style">@Translator.Translate("CREATED_BY")</label>
                    <label id="lblCreatedByValue" class="right-position text-style">@User.Identity.Name</label>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is button on page where i have print option :

```
  <div class="mr-10">
                    <div class="pull-right padding-8 mt5 col-lg-2 col-md-2">
                        <input type="submit" value="@Translator.Translate("CANCEL")" class="btn btn-block secondary-button save-changes padding-8" ng-click="CancelPayOutTicket(ticketPin)" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="pull-right padding-8 mt5 col-lg-2 col-md-2">
                        <input type="submit" value="@Translator.Translate("PAYOUT")" class="btn btn-block save-changes padding-8" ng-class="{'secondary-button':TicketsPayout.BettingSlipResult.TicketHolder.PayoutEnabled==true,'disabled_button':TicketsPayout.BettingSlipResult.TicketHolder.PayoutEnabled==false}" ng-disabled="TicketsPayout.BettingSlipResult.TicketHolder.PayoutEnabled==false" ng-click="FinishTicketPayout(ticketPin);ConfirmTicketPayOut(ticketPin,'@username')"/>
                    </div>
                 </div>
```

Is there any way to avoid `setTimeout` function and just call print function in new window and populate partial view with data?

EDIT: angular controller:

```
$scope.CheckTicket = function (ticketPin) {


           if (ticketPin != null && ticketPin != "" && ticketPin != undefined) {
            var promise = accountDataProviderService.checkTicketPayout(ticketPin);

            $scope.checkPromise = promise;

            promise.then(
           function (response) {
               $scope.showTicketPayout = true;
               $scope.TicketsPayout = response;

           },
         function (err) {
             $scope.showTicketPayout = false;
             $scope.ticketNotFound = true;
             $timeout(function ()
             {
                 $scope.ticketNotFound = false;
             }, ticketNotFound * 1000);
         });

        }
    }
    $scope.CloseMessage = function ()
    {
        $scope.ticketNotFound = false;
    }
    $scope.FinishTicketPayout = function (ticketPin)
    {


        accountDataProviderService.finishTicketPayOut(ticketPin)
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.finishTicketPayOut = response;
            localStorage.setItem("payoutTime", $scope.finishTicketPayOut.PayoutTime);
            localStorage.setItem("payoutAmount", $scope.finishTicketPayOut.PayoutAmount);

        });

    }

    $scope.ConfirmTicketPayOut = function (ticketPin, username) {
        $scope.ticketPin = ticketPin;
        localStorage.setItem("pin", ticketPin);
       accountDataProviderService.confirmTicketPayOut(ticketPin, username)
        .then(function (response) {

            $scope.confirmTicketPayOut = response;
            if ($scope.confirmTicketPayOut.Result == true) {

                var newWindow = window.open("/print")

            }
        });
        localStorage.clear();
    }
```

Comment: i dont understand rly what you want to...but maybe you should make it a promise and wait for it to resolve. please post more code...

Comment: @messerbill on click i want to open new window and populate it with data and call print function but in my case it open new window it call print function and then populate data so i get blank page....is it clear to you now?

Comment: and why dont you call the print function in the Angular Controller at the other site? You also could do this via `$(document).ready()` function at the other site. you open a link in another windows via `target="_blank"` is this what you are searching for?

Comment: i tried to call it at the other site but again i need setTimeout because it render partial view after print function and again i get blank page

Comment: plz post the code of both sites or make a fiddle

Comment: As @messerbill said, if you return a promise with your print function your problem will be solved. Also if you do not return a promise your UI will freeze even if you call the `print()` function after the UI is loaded. Look into the `Q` module for promises. It should be a very easy implementation.

Comment: @messerbill i posted my code for both pages

Comment: plz also post your angular controllers or in the best case create a fiddle

Comment: @messerbill i posted angular controller...sorry in not good with fiddle

Comment: lets continue this conversation in the chat - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84188/print-external-page

Comment: @messerbill u are there? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make the data "package" a promise inside your controller:

```
angular.module("printModule").controller('printController', ['$scope', '$window', '$q', function ($scope, $window, $q) { 


$scope.ticketPin = localStorage.getItem("pin"); 
$scope.payoutTime = localStorage.getItem("payoutTime"); 
$scope.payoutAmount = localStorage.getItem("payoutAmount"); 

var defer = $q.defer(); 
defer.resolve($scope.ticketPin); 
defer.resolve($scope.payoutTime); 
defer.resolve($scope.payoutAmount); 

defer.promise.then(function () { 
    $window.print(); 
}) 
}]);
```

have a nice day ;)