# How to create PDF document from HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS to get data from API and populate HTML table using `ng-repeat`.

Table is populated from array containing JSON arrays with data (eg. 
`vm.data = [{"x": 1, "y":2}, {"x": 1, "y":2}...])`

HTML table is customized using external stylesheet file.

**I want to create PDF file from that HTML table and possible div containing data about that table (like header).** Preferably I would like this done without jQuery, only using pure JS and AngularJS. Also table in PDF should include stylesheet info (font, font-size, color, even child background...).

One thing to notice that table have limited height, but it is scrollable on X axis (using overflow:auto). I want table shown in PDF file to be full height.

---

**Methods I tried:**

jsPDF - not customizable for tables
html-pfg (https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf) - not customizable for tables/bad documentation
([Is there an Angular way of printing a div from a HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19637312/is-there-an-angular-way-of-printing-a-div-from-a-html-page)) - Hackish/Uses jQuery
([Print a div using javascript in angularJS single page application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22189544/print-a-div-using-javascript-in-angularjs-single-page-aplication)) - Not applying CSS files
(https://github.com/sayanee/angularjs-pdf) - This is not plugin for creating pdf documents...
pdfMake
([Generate PDF from HTML using pdfMake in Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049956/generate-pdf-from-html-using-pdfmake-in-angularjs)) - This is not working because only part of table is shown on page and it is scrollable. I want full table in my PDF.

Comment: have you tried jspdf

Comment: Yes, I tried but I find it bad customizable for tables

Comment: i like pdfmake way more than jspdf

Comment: Hmmmm.... This comment made me reconsider pdfmake. I had problem including it, whenever I tried calling pdfmake it will be undefined, but now I managed to successfully do it. Now let's hope it I will be able to make good enough table

Comment: Done it! I made reports that I needed, thanks to pdfmake. Also thanks for comment, made me try it again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to create PDF reports that I needed.

Plugin I used is PDFmake and is definitely best I found, works so flawless.

Only problem I had is that I wrongly included it and that's why it didn't worked first time.