# jquery printing in rails with css

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to print a div in my rails app to a printer. I am following instructions here: [Print the contents of a DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div) but I can not get the css file to work

```
mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/stylesheets/mystyle.css.scss"     type="text/css" />');
```

The page is being printed without the CSS. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

href="/assets/stylesheets /mystyle.css.scss"

Please mention full url in above href path and try

Comment: The space was a mistake i made while while writing it here. I am using the full url but it is not working

Comment: mywindow.document.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/assets/stylesheets /mystyle.css\" type=\"text/css\" media=\"print\" />");

Comment: mywindow.print();
mywindow.close(); have you used this..or missed..Please check it..This may create issue.

Comment: I have not tested this but in this way you can use css for any div/input element. Here #cssForAnyDiv is div or any html entity id
@media print {
    #cssForAnyDiv {
        background-color: white;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
    }
}

Comment: Is above information works for you..If you have less css, specific to some divs then you can use that..

Answer (score 0):

I am not tested this but just try

```
<link media="print" rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/stylesheets/mystyle.css.scss" type="text/css" />
```

- Removed the extra spaces
- added media="print"