# Getting Plain Text from Imperavi Redactor

Tags: javascript

I am using imperavi redactor for my project. I have a requirement where by i need the plain text from the textarea instead of the content with HTML tags. I did not find any such option in the API. Is there a way out our i will have to do it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an API method for this:

https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/api-services/cleaner/#s-getflattext
(link updated)

I can't find the equivalent API method for the new Redactor X, but generally speaking, you can just strip the html tags yourself. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript).

Comment: Is there a way to Print the content of the Text area, that i can use out of the box?

Comment: Perhaps you could get the content of the redactor and put it to a special <div> and then print this <div> only. Check out how to print only the content of particular <div> container for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div