# How do I print the contents of a DIV and also include <script> tags in it

Tags: javascript, jquery

The solution provided in [Print the contents of a DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div) works for me, but alongwside passing styles I also want to pass some jQuery code to the Print Preview page. How do I do that? I tried adding    mywindow.document.write('$(document).ready(function(){ /* do this */ });');
but it is not working as expected.
This is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   function PrintElem(elem)
   {
       Popup($(elem).html());
   }

   function Popup(data) 
   {
       var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'toolbars=0,width=900,height=700,left=200,top=100,scrollbars=1,resizable=1');
       mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
       mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/checkout/orderScreen.css" media="screen" />');
       mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/checkout/orderPrint.css" media="print" />');
       mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
       mywindow.document.write(data);
       mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');          
       mywindow.focus();           
       mywindow.document.close();

       return true;
   }

</script>
```

Similar to the way I am passing stylesheets, I also want to pass some jQuery code to check the URL of the print preview page for a string and if the string exists then hide a class on the page. The jQuery code would look something like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
     if(window.location.href.indexOf("myString") > -1) {
        $('.myClass').css('display', 'none');
     }     
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want the jquery code executed on the print page or do you just want to print jquery code?

Comment: How it is working then? Please show the code you have, and explain in details, what you want it to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: please provide more informations.

Comment: @WayneEllery I want the jquery code to be executed on the print page

Comment: can't you just pass the data to the print page like "<script>alert('hi')</script>"

Comment: i tried that but it isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `/` by replacing it with `\/`, for `document.write()` to work as expected.

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
document.write("<script src='https:\/\/ajax.googleapis.com\/ajax\/libs\/jquery\/2.1.1\/jquery.min.js'><\/script><script>$(document).ready(function(){ alert('Hello World!'); });<\/script>"); // notice the esacpe "\" character
```

Comment: How about linking the jQuery too?

Comment: @Teemu To link jQuery, if you are using a CDN, you will have to escape every `/` character in the URL and also the closing script tag. Checkout my updated answer above.

Comment: @Teemu You could also use the `.replace()` function to automate this.

Comment: Thanks @RahulDesai, the fix worked for me. The missing escape was causing the issue.