# how do I print a html form along with its contents

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I made and form along with a button to print the form.  The form gets printed BUT none of the user input shows up.  Is there some way to include the user input?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/Template_plain.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>



<!-- this code from stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.1.min.js" > </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function PrintElem(elem)
    {
        Popup($(elem).html());
    }

    function Popup(data) 
    {
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=600');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
        /*optional stylesheet*/ //mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write(data);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();

        return true;
    }

</script>

<!-- end code from stack overflow -->

</style></head>

<body>

<p>Complete this form</p>

<div id="container" style="border: 2px solid; width: 600px; padding: 5px;">


  <form>
    Name:<br/>
    <input type="text" name="F_Name" size=60>
    <br/><br/>
    Street Address:<br/>
    <input type="text" name="F_Address" size=30>
    City:
    <input type="text" name="F_City" size=12>
    State:
    <input type="text" name="F_State" size=2>
    Zip Code:
    <input type="text" name="F_ZipCode" size=5">
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    <br/><br/>

</form>
<!-- end #container -->
</div> <!-- end #container -->

<input type="button" value="Print Form" onclick="PrintElem('#container')" />


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no opening `<style>` tag. Why are you closing one?

Comment: you may use the **placeholder** thing in input tag. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/ng1bcu3r/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamically typed values are not part of what `.html()` gets you. (This comes down to the difference between *properties* and *attributes*.)

You can however set the `value` *attribute* of each input field to its current value, using something like this:

```
$('form input[type=text]').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());
});
```

– then `.html()` would get you those as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/b39xpoou/ (Simplified example, using a div element to output the HTML, using only text input fields, … but should be easy enough to adapt/modify.)

Comment: What do you mean, for one text input field only? Well then remove the loop, and use a selector that targets only that one field in the place of `this`.

Comment: I have never used jquery so that's new to me.  I added a function <script type="text/javascript">
    function ZorkIt()
    {
        
       $('form input[type=text]').each(function() {
         $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());
       });

    }
</script>
and called it from the button onclick but the user input was not captured.

Comment: That just sets the value attributes (assuming you have included jQuery) – you still need to call `.html()` to get the resulting HTML code.

Comment: The button onclick looks like this. <input type="button" value="Print Form" onclick="ZorkIt();PrintElem('#container')" />  ZorkIt should run your jquery and PrintElem does use .html().  I used <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"> to get jquery.  Will try the fiddle.

Comment: I did manage to get a combination of the fiddle and the PrintElem to print the form and contents.  Don't understand the difference between that and what I did above.  When I get some time, I will post the final result as an answer for the record.  Thanks very much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example for the record.  Also note once the user's input is set as the attribute value, the reset button no longer clears the form.  Guess some more jquery is needed to fix that.  I added code to handle checkboxes but have no idea what to do with textareas.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/Template_plain.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
    <head>

    <title> </title>
    
    <!-- this code from stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div -->
    
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CopyElem(elem)
        {
           $('form input[type=text]').each(function() {
             $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());
           });

           $('form input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
             $(this).attr('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
           });
        }
    
        function PrintElem(elem)
        {
            Popup($(elem).html());
        }

        function Popup(data) 
        {
            var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=600');
            mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
            /*optional stylesheet*/ //mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
            mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
            mywindow.document.write(data);
            mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    
            mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
            mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    
            mywindow.print();
            mywindow.close();
    
            return true;
        }
    </script>
    
    <!-- end code from stack overflow -->     
    </head>
    
    <body>
     
    <p>Complete this form</p>
    
    <div id="container" style="border: 2px solid; width: 600px; padding: 5px;">
           
      <form>
        Name:<br/>
        <input type="text" name="F_Name" size="60"></input>
        <br/><br/>
        Street Address:<br/>
        <input type="text" name="F_Address" size="30"></input>
        City:
        <input type="text" name="F_City" size="12"></input>
        State:
        <input type="text" name="F_State" size="2"></input>
        Zip Code:
        <input type="text" name="F_ZipCode" size="5"></input>
        <br/><br/>
        <input type="reset" value="Reset"></input>
        <br/><br/>
     
      </form>
    
    </div> <!-- end #container -->
    
      <input type="button" value="Print" onclick="CopyElem();PrintElem('#container')" />
    
      <div id="copyoutput" style="display: none;"></div>    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```