# How to set attribute value of text area

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I am trying to print a form (no server side involved) by copying the form using $(elem).html().  The problem is that the property values the user enters are not captured.  I managed to get around this for input text areas and input check boxes using the answer supplied to my question [how do I print a html form along with its contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168593/how-do-i-print-a-html-form-along-with-its-contents) but I  have not been able to do the same for a textarea.  Here's the code I used for the text and check box fields.

```
function CopyElem(elem)
{

   $('form input[type=text]').each(function() {
     $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());
   });

   $('form input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
     $(this).attr('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
   });

   $('form textarea').each(function() {

   });

}
```

So the question is what's needed for the textareas?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415602/set-value-of-textarea-in-jquery

Comment: Text area doesn't have value attribute. This might help you `$('form textarea').text(function() {
return $(this).val();
   });`

Comment: @Satpal Since when does `<textarea>` not have a value? It's worked for me for years. The only pitfall is the stripping of `carriage returns` as noted here: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: @DevlshOne, Really `textarea` has `value` attribute?

Comment: `Attribute`, no... but jQuery will get the value every single time.

Answer (score -1):

Taking a clue from PUGAZH's comment and the question he referenced, I tried

```
     $(this).html($(this).val());
```

and that did the trick.  Don't have the least idea if that's the right thing to do but it worked for me.