# Is there a way to print directly from Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing

I found this selector:

```
document.querySelector('#print-header > div > button.print.default').click();
```

Is there a method with this selector to print directly from Chrome?

I tried with timeout too, but isn't working.

Comment: It seems that by 'directly', you mean without confirmation.

Comment: yes. i tried with --kiosk-printing mode, but don't work

Comment: That is just a selector for a button. You haven't shown us if there are any event listeners (for click, that is) bound to that element that will trigger printing. Otherwise you can simply use `window.print()`.

Comment: Wait! "Yes, [without confirmation]". This shouldn't be possible. Just think about pages printing what ever they want using visitor's printer ...

Comment: Yes, but i need it for a special function.

Comment: If any web page I visit will just print something with my printer without asking me first, I'll surely navigate away, and will never come back + report it as a malicious page too.

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** print without user confirmation.
It's a security thing, you are not allowed to control user PC from the browser.

When you open the print dialog in chrome it's like a new Tab, you have no control there.

Answer (score 1):

*(This solution needs user's confirmation)*

Use `window.print();` function or see this answer : [Bill Paetzke's answser of *Print the contents of a DIV*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2255438/2226755).

```
function PrintElem(elem)
{
    Popup($(elem).html());
}

function Popup(data) 
{
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=600');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
    /*optional stylesheet*/ //mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    mywindow.document.write(data);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();

    return true;
}
```