# Asp Print button

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have tried enough on print button code but no sake. These are my codes with images.

```
 <asp:Button ID="printButton"  style="margin-left: -0.3%;" runat="server" Text="Print Invoice" OnClientClick="javascript:window.print();" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="14pt" Width="150px" Height="40px" BackColor="#CC0000" ForeColor="White" />
```

This gives me the following output.
[image]

The problem in this output image is that it prints all the page but it has damaged my design. Like if you can see, Header is showing code instead of images. Is this any way to modify it. e.g i only want here to print the `circular logo` and the `grid-view` only.

Another code i have used on `button_click code behind` is:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "vPrint", "window.print();", true);
```

it also doesn't works for me. As i used this code when i have design my own template, but when i'm applying this on downloaded templatel, it shows me an empty page on print button output. See here.
[image: 2nd output]

I also tried JavaScript function like `window.Print()` etc. But not working, Kindly sort out this for me. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, i did'nt get your idea... Please

Comment: Please help, as im not too good

Comment: This might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div

Comment: @hamza alternative is keep another page and on button click try to navigate to that page and call only the print code

Comment: @Cal279 it only shows how to print in Html.. I want in ASp

Comment: @Webruster How sir  ? and which code ?

Comment: @HamzaJaved what content you want to post in another page just try to put it in one single  method and use that method to print in another page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use an ASP button control at all? Just use a standard html one:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #btnPrint
    {
        margin-left: -0.3%;
        width : 150px;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: #CC0000;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-size: 14pt;
    }
</style>
<input id="btnPrint" name="btnPrint" type="button" value="Print Invoice" onclick="window.print()"/>
```

Comment: same result like my first image

Comment: Sorry - I can't see your images. Blocked by Corporate proxy server. Can you create a JS Fiddle? Also, if you only want to print certain DOM elements, you probably want to add @media print styles to stylesheet, where you would set display: none; to all elements you don't want to print.

Comment: I have not any idea of JS Fiddle

Comment: :( --------------------------

Comment: Just go to: https://jsfiddle.net/, add your code, and then put a hyperlink to it in your question.

Comment: jsfiddle.net got it but i do'nt even know now what to do now

Comment: I guess follow the instructions on the website or search for help on how to use it.  That's kinds of outside the scope of the question. BTW - have you tried adding CSS media query?

Comment: Sir, i used media print, and my problem solved, as you suggested. Thanks