# element print preview is blank and prints blank pages in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I am using this jQuery code from [Print the contents of a DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div/2255438#2255438) to print the contents of an overlay div:

```
function PrintElem(elem){
        Popup($(elem).html());
}

   function Popup(data) 
{
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'title', 'height=666,width=1000');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>title-title</title>');
    /*optional stylesheet*/ //mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
    mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/main.css" type="text/css" />');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    mywindow.document.write(data);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();

    return true;
}
```

It was working perfectly fine until a recent Google Chrome update, which causes it to show blank print preview and print blank pages.

I did some research about this and found out that the best solution would probably be to add some `$(window).load(function()` to make the `print()` fire only after the popup has been fully loaded, but I am not sure how to integrate it or modify this correctly.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

As suggested by someone on the original stackoverflow question, I tried modifying the function to add

```
mywindow.document.write('<script type="text/javascript">$(window).load(function() { window.print(); window.close(); });</script>');
```

But this broke the function entirely, I guess because of the `</script>` tag in that line.

This is how my broken modified function looks like:

```
    function Popup(data) 
    {
        var mywindow = window.open('', '.com Shopping Cart', 'height=666,width=1000');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>- Shopping Cart</title>');
        /*optional stylesheet*/ //mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
        mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/main.css" type="text/css" />');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write(data);

        mywindow.document.write('<script type="text/javascript">$(window).load(function() { window.print(); window.close(); });</script>');


        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

   //     mywindow.print();
   //     mywindow.close();

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `<script></script>` tags are breaking the code, try using this line :

```
mywindow.document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript">$(window).load(function() { window.print(); window.close(); });</scr'+'ipt>')
```

And without jQuery :

```
mywindow.document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript">function PrintPage() { window.print(); window.close(); } window.onload = PrintPage;</scr'+'ipt>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding Javascript or Jquery to the content of the new window, you can delay the print() event and let the window load first.

```
function Popup(data) 
{
    var mywindow = window.open('', '316steel.com Shopping Cart', 'height=666,width=1000');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>316steel Jewelry Corporation - Shopping Cart</title>');
    /*optional stylesheet*/ //mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
    mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/main.css" type="text/css" />');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    mywindow.document.write(data);

    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

   /* Delaying the print event */ 
   setInterval(function () { 
      mywindow.document.close();
      mywindow.focus();
      mywindow.print();
      mywindow.close();    
    }, 100);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like [Sri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38138998/712526), but that didn't work for me. I used this slightly modified code and it works for IE, FireFox, Chrome and Safari. It seems Chrome and Safari need the delay to work properly. Hope this helps someone.

```
function Popup(data) 
{
    var mywindow = window.open('', '316steel.com Shopping Cart', 'height=666,width=1000');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>316steel Jewelry Corporation - Shopping Cart</title>');
    /*optional stylesheet*/ //mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
    mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/main.css" type="text/css" />');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    mywindow.document.write(data);

    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    mywindow.document.close();
    mywindow.focus();

   /* Delaying the print event */ 
   setInterval(function () { 
      mywindow.print();
      mywindow.close();    
    }, 100);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using setTimeOut function, you should be able to resolve your issue.

```
function Popup(data) 
{
    var mywindow = window.open('', '316steel.com Shopping Cart', 'height=666,width=1000');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>316steel Jewelry Corporation - Shopping Cart</title>');
    /*optional stylesheet*/ //mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
    mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/main.css" type="text/css" />');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    mywindow.document.write(data);

    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    mywindow.document.close();
    mywindow.focus();

   /* Delaying the print event */ 
    setTimeout(function () {           
            mywindow.print();
            mywindow.close();
        }, 2000);

    return true;
}
```