# Print the contents of a text file using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, printing

I have a text file in my system. I want print the contents of that text file using javascript/jquery. How can I do that. I have referred the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div). But it is simply printing from div. I need to use `window.print()` method. But how can I print the text file using javascript? Please guide me.

Answer (score 3):

First open text file and print.

```
var w = window.open('yourfile.txt'); //Required full file path.
w.print();
```

Fiddle sample : https://jsfiddle.net/shree/91459gm9/

Fiddle don't found file but its open sample file and print window to print.

Comment: Thanks @Shree. let me try. I think it will most likely to solve my problem.

Comment: font not coming correctly. I am getting some weird  font. I need the font same as test print font. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Use that code may solve your problem:-

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.1.min.js" > </script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

function PrintElem(event)
{
    var selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var result = document.getElementById("mydiv");
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        result.innerHTML = event.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsText(selectedFile);
    console.log(selectedFile);
    //Popup($('#mydiv').html());
}
function Popup(elam) 
{
    //console.log($(elam).html());return false;
    var data = $(elam).html();
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=600');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
    /*optional stylesheet*/ //mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    mywindow.document.write(data);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();

    return true;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mydiv">

</div>

<input type="file" onchange="PrintElem(event)">
<input type="button" value="Print Div" onclick="Popup('#mydiv')" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need back-end (php,rails,nodejs) support for reading file from computer and then display it on any HTML Block then Print this is most preferable way to print a file

you can use below syntax if you have back-end  setup and file must be on your server

$(document).ready(function () {

```
 $("button").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url : "Content.txt",
            dataType: "text",
            success : function (result) {
                $("#container").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```