# Print Div content only without losing other functionality

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, jstl

I have a page where I have to print only div content, this content is dynamic and will vary based on drop downvalue. Now, i want to print this content, I was able to do it successfully using

```
function printDiv(divId){
    var orginalPage= document.body.innerHTML;
    var printDiv= document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = printDiv;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = orginalPage;
}
```

but my problem is, when I am done printing the div and get back to actual page the dropdown value is getting reseting to default value. I want the value to be same as value which was selected before printing div.. for example I selected "xyz" from dropdown then after printing my div content I want xyz to be selected by default.

I will be iterating a list for this dropdown options. something like this

```
<select id="reason" >
<logic:iterate id="hs" name="hslist" type="hsData">
<option value="">select a reason </option>
<option value="<bean write name='hs' property='hsReasonId'/>">
<bean write name="hs" property="hsReasonDesc"/></option>
</logic>
</select>
```

Can someone help in fixing this...

Comment: Can you elaborate .... any code snippet is greatly appreciated

Comment: so your saying to keep body of page in new hidden div and print the required div?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div

Comment: I tired that way but when I print div the content is not aligning properly it looks total mess...

Comment: maybe you should focus on that

Comment: it is not about focus I guess

Answer (score 0):

You can use the selected attribute for select element to set the default value

Comment: I want value to be, the value which user selected before printing the div...can I do that using selected attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve with a small change.for that you want to open an extra window and assign the html in the window that you want to print.

```
function printDiv(divId){
var printDiv= document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML;
var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=800,height=500");
myWindow.document.write(printDiv);
myWindow.print();
}
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div

Comment: however, it just opens the new window but it doesn't print afterall

Answer (score -1):

As you are assigning the innerHTML back to the body the value you selcted is earlier is lost. Try printing the innerHTML of body first. I think you will be able to figure out why your drop down is not populated back.

Comment: Please explain how you print part of the html

Comment: Try this in your code. var printBody=document.body.innerHTML;winow.print(printBody);