# How to use JavaScript for print a Shadow DOM with <style> tags inside?

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom

I am trying to print a shadow dom's content through JS.

It seems easy:

```
var reportBody = document.getElementById('daily-report-old').shadowRoot.innerHTML.toString().trim();
```

after this, I have the whole content I want in the `reportBody` variable.

Then, I will trying to print it:

```
var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');
mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + document.title + '</title>');
mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
mywindow.document.write(reportBody);
mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
mywindow.document.close();
mywindow.focus();
mywindow.print();
mywindow.close();
```

this code for printing I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div) .

All I get is a blank/empty page. I suspect that some hard coded css inside the shadow dom is playing some annoying role.

Does somebody know a proper way of printing a shadow dom's content? Regards.

Comment: 1) did you try your print function by setting a simple reportBody variable? 2) what's the content of your shadom dom?

Comment: weird, in the console, the function works, that's how I did try it before, [----but in the actual code it doesnt ---] sorry, it does work

Comment: inside the shadow dom there is a huge page with lots of <style> tags and many elements with style="color: #123123" parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it seems tricky to me but:

```
var reportBody = document.getElementById('daily-report-old').shadowRoot.innerHTML.toString().trim();
var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');
mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + document.title + '</title></head><body>' + reportBody + '</body></html>');
mywindow.document.close();
mywindow.focus();
setTimeout(function () {
    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();
}, 2000);
```

solves the problem.

Hope someone could give a better answer.