# How to create a download file and not save it in server with javascript

Tags: javascript, php

i have problem about how to create button which will downloading PDF file for one div.

i tried `window.print()` like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#printBtn').on('click',function(){
            window.print();
        });

    });
```

and save it as PDF file. i don't know other ways than that and i don't want to save it on server first.

Comment: check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div

Comment: You can have the server create and deliver it _without_ saving it there. So on-the-fly generation.

Comment: @AhmedGinani i will check it, thankyou

Comment: @arkascha what do u mean? i don't get it haha

Comment: Generting a document (pdf or whatever format) on the server side does _not_ mean you have to save it to a file there. Usually such document is generated upon request by a client and transferred immediately to that client _without_ creating a server side file.

Comment: @arkascha so can i use `window.open` to generate and save file?

Comment: You implement an ajax request on the client side (so in javascript) which hands over all information required to create the document to a server side script (could be php). That script uses some PDF generation library to create the document and streams the content as a response to the request. The client side receives the response and can do with it whatever you like: print it, save it, visualize it.

Answer (score 0):

You try direct download link with using a elements ***attribute download***

```
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
```

---- OR ----

```
<button id="print" onclick="print('uname');" >Print</button>
<div id="uname">
<label>Name</label>
<label>Spider</label>
</div>

<button id="print" onclick="printContent('uname');" >Print</button>

    function print(e){var divToPrint=document.getElementById('e');

    var newWin=window.open('','Print-Window');

    newWin.document.open();

    newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">'+divToPrint.innerHTML+'</body></html>');

    newWin.document.close();

    setTimeout(function(){
        newWin.close();
    },10);
}
```

[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/audep8yv/6/)

Comment: is it for print? i need to save the file as pdf.. is it possible?