# How to get only content specific height and width in print using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am developing pos system but when I print my bill it prints in whole page I just want it should takes only specific width and only that much height which covering in div.

here is my code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>div print</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function printdiv(printpage) {
                var headstr = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>";
                var footstr = "</body>";
                var newstr = document.all.item(printpage).innerHTML;
                var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
                document.body.innerHTML = headstr+newstr+footstr;
                window.print();
                document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;
                return false;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    <input name="b_print" type="button" class="ipt"   onClick="printdiv('div_print');" value=" Print ">
        <div id="div_print">
            <h1 style="Color:Red">this will print</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print the contents of a DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div)

Comment: this will set the chartdiv height to 200px ."document.getElementById('chartdiv').style.height = '200px'"

Comment: @lonut NO I am able to print only div content by my question is when I print it take whole page height and width and I want this take only div height .Getting my question ? no white space

Answer (score 0):

The ideal solution is to use a separate CSS for printing where you specify the size restraints. 
You could use a print specific CSS stylesheet and hide everything but what you want printed. Divide your elements into two classes, one that wont print and another that will:

```
<div class="no-print">Ignore me</div><div class="something-else">Print me! 
 </div>
```

The elements in the print class should remain while the ones that are ignored should not print.

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
.no-print { display: none; }
</style>
```

As a warning, be careful with "document.all.item" as if there is more than one element found, it will return an array of elements which may be contributing to your problem.