# window.print() in Material Dialog

Tags: angular-material

when i want to use window.print() on my Material Dialog Component, I'm getting printed my navbar which is behind the dialog and also outside the dialog.
Has anyone got solution to print correctly Dialog's data?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you show your code?

Comment: I want to send the Material's Dialog data to printer, but when i use window.print() it print's only my navbar - which is not in the Material Dialog

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div