# How to copy all CSS style from one DOM to another?

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I use this method to copy a DIV from my webapp to be printed in a new tab or saved to the database, like a certificate, for example (it is an automated proccess, I can't ask the user to do that): https://stackoverflow.com/a/40389924/1062933 [*thanks!*]

```
  printForm(): void {
    let printContents: any = document.getElementById('formTerms').innerHTML;
    let w: any = window.open();
    w.document.write(printContents);
    w.document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript">' + 'window.onload = function() { window.print(); window.close(); };' + '</sc' + 'ript>');
    w.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    w.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10
  }
```

But the resulting HTML comes unformatted without the CSS it had in the main tab.

**Is there a way to also copy the CSS styles used in that DIV?**

*I am using Angular4 and Teradata Covalent*

Comment: I need this, even if I have to copy all the CSS of the original page to make it works...

Comment: `Ctrl+S` Webpage, Complete.  Find all the `.css` files.

Comment: The CSS files are generated by angular.

Comment: On every build they will have different names. That's mean man.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley should I ask the user to do that everytime I want to save a generated certificate or other component that I need him to have? aff!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know which `<style>` tags are being used to style the `div`, you can copy the contents of those into new style tags over in the new window. However, that won't include styles directly on the `div` itself.

White a bit more manual, the [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) function can give the current styling of the element, which you can then apply over in the new window. If there are children in the `div` you're copying, you'll have to do this recursively or resolve common styles into a generated style sheet.

There are examples in the linked page, but I'll copy it here:

```
// print one or all of the style properties on the element
function dumpComputedStyles(elem,prop) {

  var cs = window.getComputedStyle(elem,null);
  if (prop) {
    console.log(prop+" : "+cs.getPropertyValue(prop));
    return;
  }

  var len = cs.length;
  for (var i=0;i<len;i++) {

    var style = cs[i];
    console.log(style+" : "+cs.getPropertyValue(style));
  }

}
```