# Catching Highcharts Client Side Export response before it downloads

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have configured my application to use Highcharts client side export (https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/client-side-export), on page load I create a chart and call the `exportChart` method as shown in this example (http://jsfiddle.net/5dry1oqg/1/).

My problem is that I don't want to download the image immediately, instead I want to use it in a print version which could be called later.  What I need to know is if there is a way of intercepting the download, for instance when a Blob is created (if that's what happens).

I suspect there isn't as I don't find any documentation on this from Highcharts, any help appreciated.

Comment: I believe you can prevent the default event by event.preventDefault() for that click event. Then write down your own method to create a print view. To create a print view of a div or dom element, you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div

Comment: Please describe more precisely the process steps which you have to do, because I don't understand the question a bit.

Answer (score 1):

When you trigger `exportChart` a POST request is being sent to the highcharts servers, containing the SVG and some other values within the request body. I've checked the URL which is being called ([export.highcharts.com](https://export.highcharts.com/)) and it's a kind of a playground for chart exporting. There if you click on download, you can easily see that first a POST request is being fired with some data (JSON) as request payload (Inspect the call in Network tab). As a response you get the generated image string (e.g. `charts/chart.20bb843a8be6440e99ffcab5996c532d.png`), therefore your exported image can be accessed via the base-url (`https://export.highcharts.com/`) + the response of the POST call.

**Example:** `https://export.highcharts.com/charts/chart.20bb843a8be6440e99ffcab5996c532d.png`

I'm not 100% sure how legit this workaround is, but you can at least play around with it and maybe find a better/more suitable solution.