# Print Preview how to show only a part of view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to show only one part of web view when clicking a button.

My current css code looks like this:

```
  .wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0%; 
    top: 0%;
  }
```

html code:

```
<div class="wrapper">long content</div>
```

Initially the Print Preview used to show only one sheet, then if I remove the top:0% then Preview shows fine, it shows the whole page, but how about if I only want to print some specific part of view? Also if you could explain why removing top:0% fixed the issue of showing only one sheet so it was cutting off the content?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div

Comment: this does not print show the print option, it only opens a new window like a print version but there is no actuall print option to print the paper.

Comment: for some reason now it is working