# document.getElementById('printf').contentWindow.print() is including the html tag elements in the printout

Tags: javascript, iframe, printing

I have been attempting to print a dynamically created iFrame, then print it:

```
// CREATE iFrame 
let iframe = document.createElement("iframe"); 
iframe.setAttribute('id', 'printerIFrame'); 
iframe.setAttribute('name', 'printerIFrame'); 
iframe.setAttribute('style', ' z-index: 1000;'); 
iframe.setAttribute('media', 'print'); 

let pageContent = document.createTextNode(createPrintableText(criteria)); 

// ADD iFrame to document 
document.body.appendChild(iframe); 

// POPULATE iFrame with print material 
iframe = document.getElementById("printerIFrame"); 
body = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.appendChild(pageContent)

// GET iFrame `window`
var x = document.getElementById("printerIFrame").contentWindow;

// IF NOT IE or Edge 
x.document.close(); 
x.focus(); 
x.print(); 

iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
```

And this works... sort of. The problem is, when the print preview arrives, contained in the text are all the <[HTML]> tags that are on the iframe. And they're ignored. Instead of getting this:

Start Date: 01/01/2019
End Date: 01/31/2019

I'm getting something like this: 
Start Date: 01/01/2019<[br tag]>End Date: 01/31/2019<[br tag]>

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Comment: `pageContent` is a text node ... therefore adding it using `appendChild` will add the exact text in that variable .. try `body.innerHTML = pageContent` instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print the contents of a DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div)

Comment: Oh, you'll also need to just `let pageContent = createPrintableText(criteria);` - i.e. you don't want to create a text element, just the text is fine

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is as follows

Firstly, you are creating a text node in

```
let pageContent = document.createTextNode(createPrintableText(criteria));
```

Then you take this text node and add it to the body of the iframe

```
body.appendChild(pageContent);
```

That is why the "html" returned by `createPrintableText` is shown as is, because you've said "I want the content to be this text exactly as it is"

What you want to do is take the HTML as a string, and add it to the `body.innerHTML` as follows - the two lines marked `****` are the only required changes

```
let iframe = document.createElement("iframe"); 
iframe.setAttribute('id', 'printerIFrame'); 
iframe.setAttribute('name', 'printerIFrame'); 
iframe.setAttribute('style', ' z-index: 1000;'); 
iframe.setAttribute('media', 'print'); 

// **** assuming createPrintableText(criteria) returns the HTML you need
let pageContent = createPrintableText(criteria); 

// ADD iFrame to document 
document.body.appendChild(iframe); 

// POPULATE iFrame with print material 
iframe = document.getElementById("printerIFrame"); 
body = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

// **** add the HTML to body innerHTML - that way it's treated as HTML
body.innerHTML = pageContent;

// GET iFrame `window`
var x = document.getElementById("printerIFrame").contentWindow;

// IF NOT IE or Edge 
x.document.close(); 
x.focus(); 
x.print(); 

iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
```

Comment: Ah-ha, that's why it's working now as the new code is over-writing the text node created earlier! Thanks for explaining what's causing my original error.

Comment: @JustinMacCreery - no, not at all, there is no text node created earlier, and there is no overwriting of anything - you're confusing your own answer with mine

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it using slightly different code to send the iframe to the printer:

```
// CREATE iFrame 
let iframe = document.createElement("iframe"); 
iframe.setAttribute('id', 'printerIFrame'); 
iframe.setAttribute('name', 'printerIFrame'); 
iframe.setAttribute('style', 'display: hidden;'); // z-index: 1000;
// iframe.setAttribute('media', 'print'); 

let pageContent = document.createTextNode(createPrintableText(criteria)); 

// ADD iFrame to document 
document.body.appendChild(iframe); 

// POPULATE iFrame with print material 
iframe = document.getElementById("printerIFrame"); 
body = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.appendChild(pageContent)

// GET iFrame `window`
var x = document.getElementById("printerIFrame").contentWindow;

// CREATE new `window` using iFrame 
var newWin = window.frames["printerIFrame"];
newWin.document.write('<body>' + createPrintableFilters(criteria) + '</body>');
newWin.document.close();

// SET delay
setTimeout(function(){
    // REMOVE iFrame 
    iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe)
}, 100);
```