# How to print a page in Rails / HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

[image]I'm not sure if it's related to Rails, JavaScript or more just to some basic old HTML code.

I have a simple web app I've built with Ruby on Rails with a navbar and a sidebar at:

`layout > application.html.erb`

And the actual page (`<%= yield %>`) in the middle (classic bootstrap style I copied from bootstrap main example).

How can I add a simple Print button that lets the user print just the the actual page that the button is located at (without the navbar and sidebar)?

Answer (score 2):

here you can use

```
<%= link_to 'print', 'your_link_here', :onclick => 'window.print();return false;'%>
```

use below to hide contents you don't want to print :-

```
@media print {
  div.sidebar, div.navbar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it almost worked, the navbar did disappear from the print window, but somehow the sidebar is still there. Is there any other way to do that? maybe with a class on a div and just print that div or adding some css to hide that sidebar?

Comment: can you post the picture of `what are you expecting` and `what are you getting`.
as it's hard to provide solutions without seeing what's going on

Comment: Yes I added a screenshot to the question above.

Comment: if you are using `sidebar` and `navbar` as different components, try above line of code inside the component you want to print. Maybe that can help you

Comment: I don't know why I can't comment the answer on here but I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div as the easiest way to print just a specific div, no CSS involved.

Comment: question is closed so you are not able to comment