# I want to print only the specific div content and email results from HTML/JS page?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to use print JS/HTML page but it is printing whole page. I just want to print a specific div content, in my case it is result.

The code is as follows:

```js
function displayRadioValue() {

  let section1 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-1 > input[type="radio"]')
  let section2 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-2 > input[type="radio"]')
  let section1Total = 0
  let section2Total = 0
  let section1Question = 0
  let section2Question = 0
  let finalResults = document.querySelector('.final-results')
  let result1 = ''
  let result2 = ''
  finalResults.innerHTML = ''

  //Section 1
  section1.forEach(function(radio, index) {
    if (radio.checked) {
      section2Question++
      section1Total += +radio.value
    }
  })

  //Section 2
  section2.forEach(function(radio, index) {
    if (radio.checked) {
      section1Question++
      section2Total += +radio.value
    }
  })

  //Final Results and validation
  if (section1Total > 0 && section2Total > 0) {
    finalResults.innerHTML += genTable(section1Question, section1Total, 1)
    finalResults.innerHTML += genTable(section2Question, section2Total, 2)
  } else {
    finalResults.innerHTML = 'Snap! Please select the atleast one survey question from each section '}
    document.getElementById("control").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("toemail").href += document.getElementById("final-results").innerText;

  }
```

```css
@media print {

  #result,
  #result * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  #result {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}

table,
table tr th,
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Select a radio button and click on Submit.
</p>
<div class="section-1">

  <h2>Section 1</h2>
  question 1:
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="3">3

  <br> question 2:
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="3">3

  <br> question 3:
  <input type="radio" name="question3" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question3" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question3" value="3">3

</div>
<div class="section-2">

  <h2>Section 2</h2>
  question 1:
  <input type="radio" name="question4" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question4" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question4" value="3">3

  <br> question 2:
  <input type="radio" name="question5" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question5" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question5" value="3">3
  <br> question 3:
  <input type="radio" name="question6" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question6" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question6" value="3">3
  <br> question 4:
  <input type="radio" name="question7" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question7" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question7" value="3">3
</div>
<br>

<div class="final-results"></div>
<br>

<button type="button" onclick="displayRadioValue()">
      Submit
     </button>

<div id="control" style="display: none"><a id="toemail" href="mailto:youremail@domain.com?subject=Survey response&body=">Send to   
      email</a>&nbsp<button onclick="window.print();">Send to PDF</button></div>
```

The problem I had in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63574792/printing-an-html-page-as-pdf-produces-blank-pdf) was resolved by removing

```css
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print the contents of a DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div)

Comment: Do you still need help with this ? Or this is all sorted @jugal ?

Comment: @jugal yes i want help using the solution i am getting error "TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null "@Alwayshelping

Comment: @jugal Do you want to print the results table in the print format - Correct ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use actual div `.final-results` in the `CSS` / `@media print{}` to show the results tables only in the `window.print()` command when you click on `Print to PDF`

Also, you can add the custom `CSS` to your `PDF` as your wish to

**Edit:** I have added `querySelector`  method to add the `innerText` of your `.final-results` div in to `href` of so you can use that for `emailing` as well by clicking `send to Email`

**Live Demo:**

```js
function displayRadioValue() {
  let section1 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-1 > input[type="radio"]')
  let section2 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-2 > input[type="radio"]')
  let section1Total = 0
  let section2Total = 0
  let section1Question = 0
  let section2Question = 0
  let finalResults = document.querySelector('.final-results')
  let result1 = ''
  let result2 = ''
  finalResults.innerHTML = ''

  //Section 1
  section1.forEach(function(radio, index) {
    if (radio.checked) {
      section2Question++
      section1Total += +radio.value
    }
  })

  //Section 2
  section2.forEach(function(radio, index) {
    if (radio.checked) {
      section1Question++
      section2Total += +radio.value
    }
  })

  //Final Results and validation
  if (section1Total > 0 && section2Total > 0) {
    finalResults.innerHTML += genTable(section1Question, section1Total, 1)
    finalResults.innerHTML += genTable(section2Question, section2Total, 2)
    document.getElementById("control").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("toemail").href += document.querySelector(".final-results").innerText;
  } else {
    finalResults.innerHTML = 'Snap! Please select the atleast one survey question from each section '
  }
}

function genTable(ques, total, section) {
  var result = "<b>Section " + section + ":</b><br>"
  var tr = "<tr><th>" + total + "</th><th>" + ((total / (ques * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2) + "</th></tr>"
  result += "<table><thead><tr><th>Total Score</th><th>Percentage</th></tr></thead><tbody>" + tr + "</tbody></table>"
  return result
}
```

```css
@media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .final-results * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .final-results {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}

table,
table tr th,
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Select a radio button and click on Submit.
</p>
<div class="section-1">

  <h2>Section 1</h2>
  question 1:
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="3">3

  <br> question 2:
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="3">3

  <br> question 3:
  <input type="radio" name="question3" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question3" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question3" value="3">3

</div>
<div class="section-2">

  <h2>Section 2</h2>
  question 1:
  <input type="radio" name="question4" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question4" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question4" value="3">3

  <br> question 2:
  <input type="radio" name="question5" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question5" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question5" value="3">3
  <br> question 3:
  <input type="radio" name="question6" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question6" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question6" value="3">3
  <br> question 4:
  <input type="radio" name="question7" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question7" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question7" value="3">3
</div>
<br>

<div class="final-results"></div>
<br>

<button type="button" onclick="displayRadioValue()">
  Submit
</button>

<div id="control" style="display: none"><a id="toemail" href="mailto:youremail@domain.com?subject=Survey response&body=">Send to
    email</a>&nbsp<button onclick="window.print();">Send to PDF</button></div>
```

Comment: Showing error "TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null"

Comment: @jugal Copy my exact code the JS and HTML and CSS. Let me know.

Comment: @jugal I have edited my answer above - Check now. No errors.

Comment: I ran the code snippet given by you and it showing error.... also in my code i already change to final-result and it still coping full page in pdf ..... i also try to put my html code in body and hide the body part and put visiblity for final-result still no change

Comment: @jugal Happy to help. Happy coding :)