# I need to show Div result of HTML/Js page in bar chart?

Tags: javascript, html, bar-chart

I need to show the result of below mention code in bar chart.Is it possible to show the result of below code for survey to show in bar chart ?So i put the code here as suggested by few mate.You can see in code i am printing survey result but what i wanted to show the spider chart also but i am not know how to proceed.

[You can check code in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63576038/i-want-to-print-only-the-specific-div-content-and-email-results-from-html-js-pag/63589993#63589993)

Js file :-

```
function displayRadioValue() {

let section1 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-1 > input[type="radio"]')
let section2 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-2 > input[type="radio"]')
let section1Total = 0
let section2Total = 0
let section1Question = 0
let section2Question = 0
let finalResults = document.querySelector('.final-results')
let result1 = ''
let result2 = ''
finalResults.innerHTML = ''

//Section 1
section1.forEach(function(radio, index) {
if (radio.checked) {
  section2Question++
  section1Total += +radio.value
 }
})

//Section 2
section2.forEach(function(radio, index) {
if (radio.checked) {
  section1Question++
  section2Total += +radio.value
}
})

//Final Results and validation
if (section1Total > 0 && section2Total > 0) {
finalResults.innerHTML += genTable(section1Question, section1Total, 1)
finalResults.innerHTML += genTable(section2Question, section2Total, 2)
} else {
finalResults.innerHTML = 'Snap! Please select the atleast one survey   question from each section '}
document.getElementById("control").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("toemail").href +=   document.getElementById("final-results").innerText;

}
```

Html file :-

```
<p>
Select a radio button and click on Submit.
</p>
<div class="section-1">

<h2>Section 1</h2>
question 1:
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="3">3

<br> question 2:
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="3">3

<br> question 3:
<input type="radio" name="question3" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="question3" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="question3" value="3">3

</div>
<div class="section-2">

<h2>Section 2</h2>
question 1:
<input type="radio" name="question4" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="question4" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="question4" value="3">3

<br> question 2:
<input type="radio" name="question5" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="question5" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="question5" value="3">3
<br> question 3:
<input type="radio" name="question6" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="question6" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="question6" value="3">3
<br> question 4:
<input type="radio" name="question7" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="question7" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="question7" value="3">3
</div>
<br>

<div class="final-results"></div>
<br>

<button type="button" onclick="displayRadioValue()">
  Submit
 </button>

 <div id="control" style="display: none"><a id="toemail"  href="mailto:youremail@domain.com?subject=Survey response&body=">Send to   
  email</a>&nbsp<button onclick="window.print();">Send to PDF</button>.  </div>
```

css file :-

```
@media print {
body * {
visibility: hidden;
 }
.final-results * {
visibility: visible;
 }
 .final-results {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
 }
}

table,
 table tr th,
table tr td {
 border: 1px solid black;
 }
```

Comment: What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Comment: You need to find a chart library that has the features you are looking for. Then figure out how to take your data and map it into the format the library requires. Beyond that this question is far too broad. Is it possible? It most likely is

Comment: A simple bar chart would be ideal. Spider chart is needed when there is alot of data. In you case you have two sections 1 and 2 - total scores . So a bar chart would be ideal for you.

Comment: Can you help me with that ?@AlwaysHelping a bar chart

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Do you got time to check ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working simple bar chart for you. You can use [chartJS](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html) library to achieve the `results` you are after.

First, we need to `define` the chart `options` and in those `options` you can load your data `dynamically` which come from the `results`.

I have made two `sections` which show **Total Scored** and **Percentage** of each section as well. The `Bar Chart` will appear just below the final-results table

The `chart` data will change accordingly to the results and question scores when you click on **Show Results** `button`. The chart also appears in your `PDF` as well.

**Live Demo:**

```js
function displayRadioValue() {
  let section1 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-1 > input[type="radio"]')
  let section2 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-2 > input[type="radio"]')
  let fullName = document.querySelector('#fullName').value
  let email = document.querySelector('#email').value
  let age = document.querySelector('#age').value
  var ctx = document.querySelector('#resultsChart').getContext('2d');
  let section1Total = 0
  let section2Total = 0
  let section1Question = 0
  let section2Question = 0
  let finalResults = document.querySelector('.final-results')
  let result1 = ''
  let result2 = ''
  finalResults.innerHTML = ''

  //Section 1
  section1.forEach(function(radio, index) {
    if (radio.checked) {
      section2Question++
      section1Total += +radio.value
    }
  })

  //Section 2
  section2.forEach(function(radio, index) {
    if (radio.checked) {
      section1Question++
      section2Total += +radio.value
    }
  })

  var options = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ["Section 1", "Section 2"],
      datasets: [{
          label: 'Total Scored',
          data: [section1Question, section2Question, 30],
          backgroundColor: '#E91E63',
          borderWidth: 1
        },
        {
          label: 'Percentage %',
          data: [((section1Total / (section1Question * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2), ((section2Total / (section2Question * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2), 30],
          backgroundColor: '#004D40',
          borderWidth: 1
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        responsive: true,
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            reverse: false
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  }

  //Final Results and validation
  if (fullName.value != '' && email.value != '' && age.value != '') {
    if (section1Total > 0 && section2Total > 0) {
      finalResults.innerHTML += genDetails(fullName, email, age)
      finalResults.innerHTML += "<h2>Results</h2>"
      finalResults.innerHTML += genTable(section1Question, section1Total, 1)
      finalResults.innerHTML += genTable(section2Question, section2Total, 2)
      finalResults.innerHTML += "<h2>Chart Results</h2>"
      document.getElementById("control").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("resultsChart").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("toemail").href += document.querySelector(".final-results").innerText;
      new Chart(ctx, options); //show chart
    } else {
      finalResults.innerHTML = 'Snap! Please select the atleast one survey question from each section '
    }
  } else {
    finalResults.innerHTML = 'Snap! Please enter your name, emial, age in the first section '
  }
}

function genDetails(name, email, age) {
  var result = "<h2>Personal Info</h2>"
  result += "<b>Full name:</b> <span>" + name + "</span><br>"
  result += "<b>Email name:</b> <span>" + email + "</span><br>"
  result += "<b>Age: </b> <span>" + age + "</span><br>"
  return result
}

function genTable(ques, total, section) {
  var result = "<b>Section " + section + ":</b><br>"
  var tr = "<tr><th>" + total + "</th><th>" + ((total / (ques * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2) + "</th></tr>"
  result += "<table><thead><tr><th>Total Score</th><th>Percentage</th></tr></thead><tbody>" + tr + "</tbody></table>"
  return result
}
```

```css
canvas {
  display: none
}

@media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  canvas {
    visibility: visible;
    margin-top: 30%;
  }
  .form-control {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .final-results * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .final-results,
  .form-control {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}

table,
table tr th,
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Survey Question</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-s+xg36jbIujB2S2VKfpGmlC3T5V2TF3lY48DX7u2r9XzGzgPsa6wTpOQA7J9iffvdeBN0q9tKzRxVxw1JviZPg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="container py-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>Survey</h2>
        <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#personalInfo" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link small text-uppercase active">Personal Info</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#section1" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link small text-uppercase">Section 1</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#section2" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link small text-uppercase">Section 2</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#results" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link small text-uppercase">Results</a></li>
        </ul>
        <br>
        <div id="tabsContent" class="tab-content">
          <div id="personalInfo" class="tab-pane fade active show">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="fullName">Full Name address</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="fullName" aria-describedby="nameHelp" placeholder="Enter full name">
              <small id="nameHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Please enter your full name.</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email address</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="email" placeholder="Enter email">
              <small id="email" class="form-text text-muted">Please enter your valid email address.</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="age">Password</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="age" aria-describedby="age" placeholder="Age">
              <small id="age" class="form-text text-muted">Please enter your age in number.</small>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="section1" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div class="section-1-questions">
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 1:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios1" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">
                              1
                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input " type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios2" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios2">
                              2
                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios3" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios3">
                              3
                            </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 2:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios4" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios4">
                              1
                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios5" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios5">
                              2
                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios6" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios6">
                              3
                            </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 3:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios7" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios7">
                              1
                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios8" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios8">
                              2
                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios9" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios9">
                              3
                            </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="section2" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div class="section-2-question">
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios10" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios10">
                              1
                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios11" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios11">
                              2
                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios12" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios12">
                              3
                            </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 5:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios13" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios13">
                              1
                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios14" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios14">
                              2
                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios15" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios15">
                              3
                            </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios16" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios16">
                              1
                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios17" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios17">
                              2
                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios18" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios18">
                              3
                            </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios19" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios19">
                              1
                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios20" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios20">
                              2
                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios21" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios21">
                              3
                            </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="results" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div class="final-results"></div>
            <br>
            <canvas id="resultsChart"></canvas>
            <br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="displayRadioValue()">
                        Show Results
                    </button>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div id="control" style="display: none">
              <a id="toemail" class="btn btn-link" href="mailto:youremail@domain.com?subject=Survey response&body=">Send to
                        email</a>&nbsp;<button onclick="window.print();" class="btn btn-warning">Send to PDF</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @jugal Glad to help. Happy coding