# Show radio button question section wise as a tab for HTML/JS page

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I have created a survey but the question of the survey is coming one by one. I want to put them in section-wise in a tab so they look good. Is there any bootstrap component or anything else which I can use so that the survey question looks in a better way may be a tab or something else.adding a pic to give more clearity[image]

Html Page:-

```
    <p>
  Select a radio button and click on Submit.
</p>
<div class="section-1">

  <h2>Section 1</h2>
  question 1:
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="3">3

  <br> question 2:
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="3">3

  <br> question 3:
  <input type="radio" name="question3" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question3" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question3" value="3">3

</div>
<div class="section-2">

  <h2>Section 2</h2>
  question 1:
  <input type="radio" name="question4" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question4" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question4" value="3">3

  <br> question 2:
  <input type="radio" name="question5" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question5" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question5" value="3">3
  <br> question 3:
  <input type="radio" name="question6" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question6" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question6" value="3">3
  <br> question 4:
  <input type="radio" name="question7" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="question7" value="2">2
  <input type="radio" name="question7" value="3">3
</div>
<br>

<div class="final-results"></div>
<br>

<button type="button" onclick="displayRadioValue()">
      Submit
     </button>

<div id="control" style="display: none"><a id="toemail" href="mailto:youremail@domain.com?subject=Survey response&body=">Send to   
      email</a>&nbsp<button onclick="window.print();">Send to PDF</button></div>
```

Js page:-

```
    function displayRadioValue() {

  let section1 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-1 > input[type="radio"]')
  let section2 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-2 > input[type="radio"]')
  let section1Total = 0
  let section2Total = 0
  let section1Question = 0
  let section2Question = 0
  let finalResults = document.querySelector('.final-results')
  let result1 = ''
  let result2 = ''
  finalResults.innerHTML = ''

  //Section 1
  section1.forEach(function(radio, index) {
    if (radio.checked) {
      section2Question++
      section1Total += +radio.value
    }
  })

  //Section 2
  section2.forEach(function(radio, index) {
    if (radio.checked) {
      section1Question++
      section2Total += +radio.value
    }
  })

  //Final Results and validation
  if (section1Total > 0 && section2Total > 0) {
    finalResults.innerHTML += genTable(section1Question, section1Total, 1)
    finalResults.innerHTML += genTable(section2Question, section2Total, 2)
  } else {
    finalResults.innerHTML = 'Snap! Please select the atleast one survey question from each section '}
    document.getElementById("control").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("toemail").href += document.getElementById("final-results").innerText;

  }
```

Style page:-

```
    @media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .final-results * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .final-results {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}

table,
table tr th,
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Are you still looking for a tab solution or all good here ? How do you want to tab to look like - its very unclear

Comment: Yes,I want to show each section as tab or toggle and when i click that section than question should be appear @AlwaysHelping

Comment: Can you draw like a picture or something to show how you want them to look like

Comment: I have added a pic please check.@AlwaysHelping

Comment: You will have different quuestions in other section ?

Comment: Yes i will have different question and no of question may also differ... should be same like code i have pasted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220546/discussion-between-jugal-and-alwayshelping).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is fully working code for you. I am using `bootstrap` and `tab section` classes to get the `desired` results.

Also, i have created each `fieldsets` of each question so that its `easy` for your do some `CSS` and customise the HTML as you want to or add more questions to it later on!

I have added the `results` section which will show the results when one question is selected from each section. As well as `Send to PD`F and `Send to Email` is working fine.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
function displayRadioValue() {
  let section1 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-1 > input[type="radio"]')
  let section2 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-2 > input[type="radio"]')
  let section1Total = 0
  let section2Total = 0
  let section1Question = 0
  let section2Question = 0
  let finalResults = document.querySelector('.final-results')
  let result1 = ''
  let result2 = ''
  finalResults.innerHTML = ''

  //Section 1
  section1.forEach(function(radio, index) {
    if (radio.checked) {
      section2Question++
      section1Total += +radio.value
    }
  })

  //Section 2
  section2.forEach(function(radio, index) {
    if (radio.checked) {
      section1Question++
      section2Total += +radio.value
    }
  })

  //Final Results and validation
  if (section1Total > 0 && section2Total > 0) {
    finalResults.innerHTML += genTable(section1Question, section1Total, 1)
    finalResults.innerHTML += genTable(section2Question, section2Total, 2)
    document.getElementById("control").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("toemail").href += document.querySelector(".final-results").innerText;
  } else {
    finalResults.innerHTML = 'Snap! Please select the atleast one survey question from each section '
  }
}

function genTable(ques, total, section) {
  var result = "<b>Section " + section + ":</b><br>"
  var tr = "<tr><th>" + total + "</th><th>" + ((total / (ques * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2) + "</th></tr>"
  result += "<table><thead><tr><th>Total Score</th><th>Percentage</th></tr></thead><tbody>" + tr + "</tbody></table>"
  return result
}
```

```css
@media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .final-results * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .final-results {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}

table,
table tr th,
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Survey Question</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <style>

  </style>
  <section class="container py-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>Survey</h2>
        <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#section1" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link small text-uppercase active">Section 1</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#section2" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link small text-uppercase">Section 2</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#results" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link small text-uppercase">Results</a></li>
        </ul>
        <br>
        <div id="tabsContent" class="tab-content">
          <div id="section1" class="tab-pane fade active show">
            <div class="section-1-questions">
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 1:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios1" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input " type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios2" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios2">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios3" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios3">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 2:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios4" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios4">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios5" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios5">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios6" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios6">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 3:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios7" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios7">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios8" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios8">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios9" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios9">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div id="section2" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div class="section-2-question">
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios10" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios10">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios11" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios11">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios12" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios12">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 5:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios13" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios13">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios14" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios14">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios15" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios15">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios16" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios16">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios17" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios17">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios18" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios18">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios19" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios19">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios20" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios20">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios21" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios21">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="results" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div class="final-results"></div>
            <br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="displayRadioValue()">
                            Show Results
                        </button>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div id="control" style="display: none">
              <a id="toemail" class="btn btn-link" href="mailto:youremail@domain.com?subject=Survey response&body=">Send to
                                email</a>&nbsp;<button onclick="window.print();" class="btn btn-warning">Send to PDF</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ... this is what i needed

Comment: @jugal Happy to hear that. Happy coding.

Comment: there is one issue with the code result of section is not coming correctly ... it is showing final result with total question and answer...Please help me to correct it.... for both the section result is coming same

Comment: @jugal Ahh i see why. Just change `<div class="section-1">` before the question 4 change this to `<div class="section-2">` - then it will all good.

Comment: i have already made that change but the result is still having the same issue@AlwaysHelping

Comment: @jugal okay sure. Give me 30 minutes I will fix it up for you just to help you out anyway. I am just busy with something hope that’s okay.

Comment: @jugal check my last edit. Each section is calculated perfectly. We just need to add class into the each `input` div's. All working now.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... it is working properly ... one more thing i have raise one question do you have any idea about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63590838/i-need-to-show-div-result-of-html-js-page-in-spider-chart

Comment: @jugal Yeah sure. I can do that one too. But will take as we need to use library or something similar to show a chart to display result. What kind chart you want. A pie chart, bar chart. just add your specification in the question to make it clear.

Comment: I have mention i need spider chart .. if possible @AlwaysHelping

Comment: Do you able to check ?@AlwaysHelping

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Bootstrap JS Tab**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#section1">section 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#section2">section 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#section3">section 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active container" id="section1">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane container" id="section2">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane container" id="section3">...</div>
    </div>
```

Refer [www.w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_ref_js_tab.asp)

Answer (score 1):

There is a section called Pills in this bootstrap official documentation, that might help you, find the related link [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/)

Answer (score 1):

In head section please add:

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

At the last of the body section, please add:

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Here's your HTML code:

```html
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="section1-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#section1" role="tab" aria-controls="section1"
                aria-selected="true">Section 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="section2-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#section2" role="tab" aria-controls="section2"
                aria-selected="false">Section 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="section3-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#section3" role="tab" aria-controls="section3"
                aria-selected="false">Section 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="section1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="section1-tab">
            question 1:
            <input type="radio" name="question1" value="1">1
            <input type="radio" name="question1" value="2">2
            <input type="radio" name="question1" value="3">3

            <br> question 2:
            <input type="radio" name="question2" value="1">1
            <input type="radio" name="question2" value="2">2
            <input type="radio" name="question2" value="3">3

            <br> question 3:
            <input type="radio" name="question3" value="1">1
            <input type="radio" name="question3" value="2">2
            <input type="radio" name="question3" value="3">3
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="section2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="section2-tab">
            question 1:
            <input type="radio" name="question1" value="1">1
            <input type="radio" name="question1" value="2">2
            <input type="radio" name="question1" value="3">3

            <br> question 2:
            <input type="radio" name="question2" value="1">1
            <input type="radio" name="question2" value="2">2
            <input type="radio" name="question2" value="3">3

            <br> question 3:
            <input type="radio" name="question3" value="1">1
            <input type="radio" name="question3" value="2">2
            <input type="radio" name="question3" value="3">3
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="section3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="section3-tab">
            question 1:
            <input type="radio" name="question1" value="1">1
            <input type="radio" name="question1" value="2">2
            <input type="radio" name="question1" value="3">3

            <br> question 2:
            <input type="radio" name="question2" value="1">1
            <input type="radio" name="question2" value="2">2
            <input type="radio" name="question2" value="3">3

            <br> question 3:
            <input type="radio" name="question3" value="1">1
            <input type="radio" name="question3" value="2">2
            <input type="radio" name="question3" value="3">3
        </div>
    </div>
```