# Send HTML/Js page result to mailbox with user typed email address

Tags: javascript, html

I have created js/html page and result of this page i am trying to send to mail box.Currently i am using

```
<a id="toemail" class="btn btn-link" href="mailto:youremail@domain.com?subject=Survey response&body=">Send to
                            email</a>&nbsp;<button onclick="window.print();" class="btn btn-warning">Send to PDF</button>
```

But it is opening the option to select a mail box and than you can send it typing mail id.But i want something like a box in which whatever mail id i have write mail should be send to that mail box.
Below is the code :-
Js file

```
    function displayRadioValue() {
  let section1 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-1 > input[type="radio"]')
  let section2 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-2 > input[type="radio"]')
  let section1Total = 0
  let section2Total = 0
  let section1Question = 0
  let section2Question = 0
  let finalResults = document.querySelector('.final-results')
  let result1 = ''
  let result2 = ''
  finalResults.innerHTML = ''

  //Section 1
  section1.forEach(function(radio, index) {
    if (radio.checked) {
      section2Question++
      section1Total += +radio.value
    }
  })

  //Section 2
  section2.forEach(function(radio, index) {
    if (radio.checked) {
      section1Question++
      section2Total += +radio.value
    }
  })

  //Final Results and validation
  if (section1Total > 0 && section2Total > 0) {
    finalResults.innerHTML += genTable(section1Question, section1Total, 1)
    finalResults.innerHTML += genTable(section2Question, section2Total, 2)
    document.getElementById("control").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("toemail").href += document.querySelector(".final-results").innerText;
  } else {
    finalResults.innerHTML = 'Snap! Please select the atleast one survey question from each section '
  }
}

function genTable(ques, total, section) {
  var result = "<b>Section " + section + ":</b><br>"
  var tr = "<tr><th>" + total + "</th><th>" + ((total / (ques * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2) + "</th></tr>"
  result += "<table><thead><tr><th>Total Score</th><th>Percentage</th></tr></thead><tbody>" + tr + "</tbody></table>"
  return result
}
```

HTML File

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Survey Question</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <style>

  </style>
  <section class="container py-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>Survey</h2>
        <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#section1" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link small text-uppercase active">Section 1</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#section2" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link small text-uppercase">Section 2</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#results" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link small text-uppercase">Results</a></li>
        </ul>
        <br>
        <div id="tabsContent" class="tab-content">
          <div id="section1" class="tab-pane fade active show">
            <div class="section-1-questions">
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 1:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios1" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input " type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios2" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios2">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios3" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios3">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 2:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios4" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios4">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios5" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios5">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios6" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios6">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 3:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios7" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios7">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios8" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios8">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios9" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios9">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div id="section2" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div class="section-2-question">
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios10" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios10">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios11" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios11">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios12" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios12">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 5:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios13" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios13">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios14" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios14">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios15" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios15">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios16" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios16">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios17" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios17">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios18" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios18">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios19" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios19">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios20" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios20">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios21" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios21">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="results" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div class="final-results"></div>
            <br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="displayRadioValue()">
                            Show Results
                        </button>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div id="control" style="display: none">
              <a id="toemail" class="btn btn-link" href="mailto:youremail@domain.com?subject=Survey response&body=">Send to
                                email</a>&nbsp;<button onclick="window.print();" class="btn btn-warning">Send to PDF</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Style sheet:-

```
    @media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .final-results * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .final-results {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}

table,
table tr th,
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `form` HTML with email input in it to store the `email` address user `entered` so that can use to send to `mail`

On clicking `Send to email` button you will just a `form` where user can type in the `email` address with `send` button in it. If user `decide` to change the mind i have added a `close` button as well to hide the form.

When you have `entered` the email address you can press `send` button and its will generate the `href` data so that can be used as `mail` data. In there you will the user `typed` email address will be there as `to` Email.

Lastly, if you did `not` type anything in the `email` address input you will see an `alert` will popup which will tell you enter an `email` address.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
function displayRadioValue() {
  let section1 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-1 > input[type="radio"]')
  let section2 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-2 > input[type="radio"]')
  let section1Total = 0
  let section2Total = 0
  let section1Question = 0
  let section2Question = 0
  let finalResults = document.querySelector('.final-results')
  let result1 = ''
  let result2 = ''
  finalResults.innerHTML = ''

  //Section 1
  section1.forEach(function(radio, index) {
    if (radio.checked) {
      section2Question++
      section1Total += +radio.value
    }
  })

  //Section 2
  section2.forEach(function(radio, index) {
    if (radio.checked) {
      section1Question++
      section2Total += +radio.value
    }
  })

  //Final Results and validation
  if (section1Total > 0 && section2Total > 0) {
    finalResults.innerHTML += genTable(section1Question, section1Total, 1)
    finalResults.innerHTML += genTable(section2Question, section2Total, 2)
    document.getElementById("control").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    finalResults.innerHTML = 'Snap! Please select the atleast one survey question from each section '
  }
}

function genTable(ques, total, section) {
  var result = "<b>Section " + section + ":</b><br>"
  var tr = "<tr><th>" + total + "</th><th>" + ((total / (ques * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2) + "</th></tr>"
  result += "<table><thead><tr><th>Total Score</th><th>Percentage</th></tr></thead><tbody>" + tr + "</tbody></table>"
  return result
}

//Show email input form
let showEmailInput = document.querySelector('.toemail-form')

function toEmail() {
  showEmailInput.classList.remove('d-none') //show form
  let finalResults = document.querySelector('.final-results').innerText;
  let sendEmail = document.querySelector('.toEmail')
  sendEmail.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let getEmail = document.querySelector('#exampleInputEmail1') //get value
    if (getEmail.value == '') {
      alert('Please enter a valid email address')
    } else {
      sendEmail.href = 'mailto:' + getEmail.value + '?subject=Survey response&body=' + finalResults //assign the email structure
      getEmail.value = '' //set value to null
    }
  })
}

//Close email input form
function closeToEmail(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  showEmailInput.classList.add('d-none') //hide form
}
```

```css
   @media print {
     body * {
       visibility: hidden;
     }

     .final-results * {
       visibility: visible;
     }

     .final-results {
       position: absolute;
       left: 0;
       top: 0;
       right: 0;
       bottom: 0;
     }
   }

   table,
   table tr th,
   table tr td {
     border: 1px solid black;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Survey Question</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <style>

  </style>
  <section class="container py-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>Survey</h2>
        <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#section1" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link small text-uppercase active">Section 1</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#section2" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link small text-uppercase">Section 2</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#results" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link small text-uppercase">Results</a></li>
        </ul>
        <br>
        <div id="tabsContent" class="tab-content">
          <div id="section1" class="tab-pane fade active show">
            <div class="section-1-questions">
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 1:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios1" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">
                           1
                         </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input " type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios2" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios2">
                           2
                         </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios3" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios3">
                           3
                         </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 2:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios4" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios4">
                           1
                         </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios5" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios5">
                           2
                         </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios6" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios6">
                           3
                         </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 3:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios7" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios7">
                           1
                         </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios8" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios8">
                           2
                         </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios9" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios9">
                           3
                         </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div id="section2" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div class="section-2-question">
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios10" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios10">
                           1
                         </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios11" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios11">
                           2
                         </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios12" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios12">
                           3
                         </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 5:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios13" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios13">
                           1
                         </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios14" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios14">
                           2
                         </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios15" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios15">
                           3
                         </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios16" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios16">
                           1
                         </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios17" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios17">
                           2
                         </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios18" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios18">
                           3
                         </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios19" value="1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios19">
                           1
                         </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios20" value="2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios20">
                           2
                         </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios21" value="3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios21">
                           3
                         </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="results" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div class="final-results"></div>
            <br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="displayRadioValue()">
                 Show Results
               </button>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div id="control" style="display: none">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="toEmail()">Send to Mail</button>&nbsp;<button onclick="window.print();" class="btn btn-warning">Send to PDF</button>
            </div>
            <form>
              <div class="form-group d-none toemail-form">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Enter Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Enter email address above</small>
                <a class="btn btn-success toEmail" href="#" role="button">Send</a>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="closeToEmail(event)">Close</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot do you got the time to check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63590838/i-need-to-show-div-result-of-html-js-page-in-spider-chart .... even if not spider chart any other char how do we show that ?