# Print the contents of a div - with stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to generate printing innerHTML elements of a `div` by javascript, so I wrote some code based on [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div). But I want to add another function: I want the printed elements to include not only the innerHTML of the `div` but its css from `<stylesheet>` as well. So I modified the code as below, but it doesn't seem to be working well.

```
<style>
#divID {
    some css...
}
<style>

function printdiv() {
    var headstr = "<html><head><title>file_name</title></head><body>";
    var footstr = "</body></html>";
    var newstrstyle = document.getElementsByTagName("style")[0].innerHTML; // is this right?
    var newstr = document.getElementById('divID').innerHTML;
    var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = headstr + '<style>' + newstrstyle + '</style>' + newstr + footstr;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;
    return false;
}
```

I want to bring the CSS from stylesheet instead of adding style values into the string, because what I'm working on has editable css. How should I improve the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `newstr` contains the content of the `div`, but the `div` with the `id` `"divID"` itself not. It follows that the `#divID` css selector won't match to any `div`-s, so the styles will not be applied.

To fix this the `"<div id='divID'>"` itself needs to be added, so the fixed function looks following:

```
function printdiv() {
  var headstr = "<html><head><title>file_name</title></head><body>";
  var footstr = "</body></html>";
  var newstrstyle = document.getElementsByTagName("style")[0].innerHTML; // is this right? -> yes it is
  var newstr = document.getElementById("divID").innerHTML;
  var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
  document.body.innerHTML =
    headstr +
    "<style>" +
    newstrstyle +
    "</style>" +
    "<div id='divID'>" + // this div was missing
    newstr +
    "</div>" + // closing the added div
    footstr;
  window.print();
  document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;
  return false;
}
```

If you want to check a live example, here is the stackblitz code where I figured it out:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-madufb?file=index.js

Answer (score 0):

1. there is no need to create a new window,you just need to hide other elements when print,add this:

```
    <style media="print">
        body>*:not(.mydiv){
            display: none;
        }
        .mydiv{display: block;}
    </style>
```

or this in ref css file if link to outer css

```
@media print{
body>*:not(.none){
    display: none;
}
.none{display: block;}
```

}

2. then change the function to this:

```
    function printDiv{window.print()}
```

3. if you dont want to show div in html which you want to print ,you can add style to hide it:

```
    <style>.mydiv{display: none;}</style>
```