# How add print button to blogger reciept website?

Tags: html, css, blogger, google-blogger-api

how can I add a print button to my recipe website hosted on blogger.com?
I have this recipe website and I wanted to add a print button on the website so users who visit my blog will be able to print the recipe.

Comment: u meant print Recipe ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with printing the whole page then you can use this code block:

```
<button onclick="window.print()">Print this page</button>
```

If you want to just print the recipe, then you'll need to tag it using an HTML ID the best way to implement a solution like that would be as follows:
HTML:

```
<div id="recipe">
       <!-- Your HTML for the recipe goes here -->
</div>
<button onclick="printDIV(recipe)">Print Recipe</button>
```

And a bit of Javascript: (From this post: [Print the contents of a DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div) )

```
function printDIV(div) {
       var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');

       mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + document.title  + '</title>');
       mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
       mywindow.document.write('<h1>' + document.title  + '</h1>');
       mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML);
       mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

       mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
       mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

       mywindow.print();
       mywindow.close();
}
```

To change the size at which it prints you can change the height and width parameters in the window.open() function.