# How to print an specific DIV with its CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I need to print an specific DIV, but every other post I have seen doesn't include the styles within the DIV, is there a way to do this with one function in javascript?

I have already seen this and other posts
[Print the contents of a DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div)

Comment: What do you mean by "print"?

Comment: Print i mean to open the optiion to print in a paper like control+p

Comment: You want to print a specific element while preserving the styles applied to it?

Comment: yes, so far, all other examples doesnt save the styles of the div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select all other elements and hide them from the page (excluding the target with the use of the [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) CSS pseudo class), then call `window.print()` to print the page:

```js
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.body.querySelectorAll(':not(.red)').forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
  window.print();
})
```

```css
div{
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid;
}
.red{
  background-color:red;
}
.blue{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
red
</div>
<div class="blue">
blue
</div>
<button id="btn">Print Red div</button>
```

If you want to create a function that accepts an element as a parameter, you can loop through all elements and check whether the current item being looped through is the parameter. If it isn't, hide the element.

Demo:

```js
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  printWithStyles(document.querySelector('.red'));
})

function printWithStyles(e){
  document.body.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(f => f === e ? '' : f.style.display="none");
  window.print();
}
```

```css
div{
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid;
}
.red{
  background-color:red;
}
.blue{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
red
</div>
<div class="blue">
blue
</div>
<button id="btn">Print Red div</button>
```

Unfortunately, the function above **hides children of the element**, which can cause issues. We can counter this by checking whether the element looped through is included in the parameter:

```js
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  printWithStyles(document.querySelector('.red'));
})

function printWithStyles(e){
  document.body.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(f => e.contains(f) ? '' : f.style.display="none");
  window.print();
}
```

```css
div{
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid;
}
.red{
  background-color:red;
}
.blue{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
<h1>red</1>
</div>
<div class="blue">
blue
</div>
<button id="btn">Print Red div</button>
```

To unhide all the elements after printing, a lazy way to do it would be:

```js
document.body.querySelector("*").forEach(e => e.style.display="none");
```

<sup>That will show hidden elements prior to printing</sup>

Comment: And if I want to use it as a function that works with any element in the HTML in my whole project, is there a way to not specify the .red class?

Comment: @DanielAltamar Sorry for the delay. I've updated my post.

Comment: you have save my life, but I have a question, to use the function, the query selector would pick the class i write? would owrk with an specific id?

Comment: what i understood with your edit, is that if my element class is "container" , i should write =>  printWithStyles(document.querySelector('.container'));
})

Comment: I tried this way  with the run code snippet in StackOverflow, but it didnt showed me the red, as if it ignored the style that gave it the red color

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235196/discussion-between-spectric-and-daniel-altamar).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do so!

```js
  $('a.printPage').click(function(){
          $('#report-summary').show();
             window.print();
             return false;
  });
```

```css
#report-summary {

}
@page { size:  auto; margin: 25mm 25mm 25mm 25mm; } 
@media print {
  #search,
  .printPage {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div id="report-summary">
Content here ...

</div>
  <div class="printbtn">
    <a class="printPage" href="#">Print Report</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Is it posible to do it without Jquery?