# How to open print popup on same tab to print base64 pdf?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, printing, base64

I have a base64 pdf on client side, I want to open the print dialog on *same tab* in browser but could not find a way to do it.

I explored some answers like `window.open()` but it opens print dialog in another tab

Can somebody tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: `window.print()`?   It's unclear how the pdf is related to the print requirement / how the pdf is loaded/displayed.   Tell users to press ctrl+p?  Or alt-f-p?

Comment: It will print the whole page, but I want to print the pdf on click of button that is not present on the page

Comment: You want to print something that's not on the page?  Where exactly is the PDF?  Can't users view the PDF and click the PDFs print button?   Did you want to *force* print?  ie not give the user the option to print but just print it?

Comment: I have a page where I show the details of a specific order, now I have 2 buttons - download and print invoice for the same order, so on print button, I generate invoice and make a pdf, to send it on the client side, I am converting it to base64, so now I want to print that base64 pdf

Comment: Numerous, different solutions on this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div

Answer (score 0):

You can use `print-js` library
You only have to pass base64 pdf and it will open the print popup by itself.

`printJS({ printable: "your_base64_of_pdf", type: 'pdf' });`